# How to git log in reverse order?

Tags: git, git-log

I recently learned that I can get hg log to print the history in reverse order with:

```
hg log -r :
```

So of course I tried:

```
git log -r :
```

Well, it didn't work. So what is the command to do the same thing in git?

Comment: `man git-log` grep reverse.

Comment: `man git-log` `/reverse` and press enter.

Comment: For clarity, according to [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log--r) `-r` in GIT translates to: "Show recursive diffs."

Answer (score 475, accepted):

Use the `--reverse` option:

```
git log --reverse
```

Comment: Note that e.g. `git log -10 --reverse` would get 10 **last** commits *then* reverse list.

Comment: You could create a git alias: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553786/how-do-i-alias-commands-in-git

Comment: This also works (currently) for `git show`, even though the documentation doesn't mention it.  E.g. `git show origin/master.. --reverse`

Comment: I use `git gol` for `git log --reverse`

Answer (score 16):

You don't need to type `--reverse` all the time, nor do you need a bash function. You can just create a git alias. Open up your favorite text editor and open up your global `.gitconfig` file. It's usually found in your home directory.

Navigate to or create a section like this:

```
[alias]
    lg = log -10 --reverse
```

That creates a git alias that grabs the ten most recent commits *then* reverses that list so the most recent of those 10 is at the bottom. Now you can simply run:

> git lg

Answer (score 13):

[Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-nar%C4%99bski)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798822/can-i-get-git-log-to-print-the-history-in-reverse-order#comment2836449_2798833) ("Note that e.g. `git log -10 --reverse` would get 10 last commits *then* reverse list") has been clarified in Git 2.11 (Q4 2016):

See [commit 04be694](https://github.com/git/git/commit/04be69478fda74fbce91a6775e5b5946c3cde61e) (27 Sep 2016) by [Pranit Bauva (`pranitbauva1997`)](https://github.com/pranitbauva1997).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 54a9f14](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54a9f14743748ada4bef3caffa45c6170ae4da32), 11 Oct 2016)</sup>

> ### `rev-list-options`: clarify the usage of `--reverse`
>
> Users often wonder if the oldest or the newest `n` commits are shown by [`log -n --reverse`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/04be69478fda74fbce91a6775e5b5946c3cde61e/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L640-L643).
> Clarify that `--reverse` kicks in only *after* deciding which commits are to be shown to unconfuse them.

See [Commit Limiting](https://github.com/git/git/blob/04be69478fda74fbce91a6775e5b5946c3cde61e/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L1-L14).

Comment: But what if you want the reverse before the -n? I can't seem to figure it out. (aka the first commit)

Comment: It might be a bit inneficient but this worked for me `git log --reverse --format=%cd | head -n 1`

Answer (score 3):

I combined few of suggested one into one and I created an alias.

```
git log -10 --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --reverse
```

```
alias gl='git log -10 --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --reverse'
```

Comment: reverse is broken

Answer (score 3):

If you want a `git --graph` with reversed order, you can't make use of `--reverse` unfortunately, but you can make use of `tac`:

```bash
git log --graph --color | tac
```

Note that `--color` is important here.

As a git alias:

```bash
git config --global alias.logr '!git log --graph --color | tac'
```

(Then of course add your favorite flags to `git log --graph` ;)

Answer (score 1):

None of above work... except this one with recent commit message + stats

```
git log --graph --stat
```

More snippet ~/.gitconfig:

```
lg1 = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all
lg2 = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)%n''          %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)' --all
lg = !"git lg1"
lg3 = log -10 --reverse --abbrev-commit
```

Comment: When using `--graph` you can't get results in reverse order out of the box, as git doesn't allow `--reverse` on top of `--graph`. See my answer for a solution

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bashrc function (assuming you are on a unixy os)

```
function git_logr {

    git log --reverse

}
```

Comment: Easier approach would be to add an alias for something this simple:
`git config --global alias.logr 'log --reverse'`
Invoke using: git logr <additional arguments>