# git: list all files with owner/identity at first commit (or rather, the first user to commit the file)

Tags: git

How do I, using git, list all files in a particular directory together with the owner/identity of those files at first commit?

Is getting slices of information like this across many files usually difficult?

Edit: Okay, git doesn't provide a direct way to do this, but it does store who commits various files, right?  I need this list in a particular directory so I can get a sense of which files I'm 'responsible' for.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$ cd thatdirectory
$ git ls-files |
  while read fname; do
    echo "`git log --reverse --format="%cn" "$fname" | head -1` first added $fname"
  done
```

The "first added" can be misleading in case of renames.

Refs:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats  (see `placeholders` under `format:<string>`)

Comment: This will only list files in the current tree. If you need to see paths that existed in prior versions or different branches, look at my answer.

Comment: I'm using git 2.20.1 and this solution lists the last modifier not the first. This is because the -1 is applied before the --reverse as specified in the man page for git log:

"Note that these are applied before commit ordering and formatting options, such as --reverse."

Comment: I've updated the answer based on @david-snape's comment

Answer (score 6):

I happened to run into a similar situation. The accepted answer is working, but why don't you guys use `find` with working copy?

```
find . -type f -exec git log --reverse --format="{} %cn" -1 {} \;
```

Comment: This is nice and short. The fact that it makes the filesystem leading could be a disadvantage

Comment: This answer does not work as expected because the list is limited to one commit and *then* reversed, so you will actually get the most recent commit author with this command. See here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39997772/1883900

Answer (score 4):

A very straightforward approach would be

```sh
git rev-list --objects --all |
    cut -d' ' -f2- |
    sort -u |
    while read name; do 
         git --work-tree=. log --reverse --format="%cn%x09$name" -- "$name" | head -n1
    done
```

Caveats:

- This shows the first author name (`%an`) of each path that exists *in the object database* (not just in (any) current revision). You may also want the committer name (`%cn`), though be aware that if person B rebased a commit from person A that created the file, B will be the committer and A will be the author.
- The --all flag signifies that you want all objects on all branches. To limit scope, replace it by the name of the branch/tag or just by `HEAD`
- *n*<sup>2</sup> performance (doesn't scale well for very large repo's)
- improper output if the pathname contains formatting sequences (e.g. %H etc.)

It will start out with the empty name, which is the root tree object.

Comment: Note that in its current form, this script needs to be run from the root of the repository. It would be nice if it could filter only the files within the current directory, like in @holygeek's answer.

Comment: @waldyrious That's simple: just insert `| grep '^path/to/subfolder/'` after the sort

Comment: It's a pity that the filtering can't (can it?) be done in the git rev-list command. With a grep, the script spends time processing information that is later thrown away. In any case, I'd suggest editing the answer to mention the need to be in the root of the repository to run this.

Comment: @waldyrious `rev-list` can do filtering, but  not in `--objects` mode (it's actually a different algorithm). The time spent throwing away information is likely insignificant (the cost of 2 subprocesses and a memory buffer, how large is your object database, really?). I'm not sure git would be able to avoid doing the same work anyhow. Adding `--work-tree` obviates the need to be in the root of the repo.

Answer (score 1):

To do this efficiently,

```
git log --raw --date-order --reverse --diff-filter=A --format=%H%x09%an \
| awk -F$'\t' '
       /^[^:]/   {thisauthor=$2}
       $1~/A$/   {print thisauthor "\t" $2}
'
```

with maybe a `|sort -t$'\t' -k1,1` or something to make it a bit prettier

Answer (score 0):

Using git itself, this is not possible.  Git does not keep track of the owner of the file.

Comment: Duly noted, I'll reword my question