# Git log shows first N commits instead of last

Tags: git

I got myself into a situation I don't know how to undo. A while back I searched for how to quickly show the first git commit message. I did what I shouldn't: tried every command I found and checked whether it worked without thinking about it. I eventually found one.

However I'm now in a situation where running a normal `git log` shows me the first N commits and not the latest N, as expected. This happens on every git repo I have.

Things I've tried:

- Cloning one the of repos into another folder to ensure that was nothing in my `.git/config`;
- Deleted my `~/.gitconfig` to remove yet another configuration source.

The problem, however, persists. Where else could have this been saved? I'm not sure if this is relevant but I'm on Mac OS.

Does anyone have any tips?

Edit 1:
Result of running `alias | grep git` (this is a massive list because of the oh my zsh aliases, I believe):

```
g=git
ga='git add'
gaa='git add --all'
gap='git apply'
gapa='git add --patch'
gau='git add --update'
gav='git add --verbose'
gb='git branch'
gbD='git branch -D'
gba='git branch -a'
gbd='git branch -d'
gbda='git branch --no-color --merged | command grep -vE "^(\+|\*|\s*(master|develop|dev)\s*$)" | command xargs -n 1 git branch -d'
gbl='git blame -b -w'
gbnm='git branch --no-merged'
gbr='git branch --remote'
gbs='git bisect'
gbsb='git bisect bad'
gbsg='git bisect good'
gbsr='git bisect reset'
gbss='git bisect start'
gc='git commit -v'
'gc!'='git commit -v --amend'
gca='git commit -v -a'
'gca!'='git commit -v -a --amend'
gcam='git commit -a -m'
'gcan!'='git commit -v -a --no-edit --amend'
'gcans!'='git commit -v -a -s --no-edit --amend'
gcb='git checkout -b'
gcd='git checkout develop'
gcf='git config --list'
gcl='git clone --recurse-submodules'
gclean='git clean -id'
gcm='git checkout master'
gcmsg='git commit -m'
'gcn!'='git commit -v --no-edit --amend'
gco='git checkout'
gcount='git shortlog -sn'
gcp='git cherry-pick'
gcpa='git cherry-pick --abort'
gcpc='git cherry-pick --continue'
gcsm='git commit -s -m'
gd='git diff'
gdca='git diff --cached'
gdct='git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)'
gdcw='git diff --cached --word-diff'
gds='git diff --staged'
gdt='git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r'
gdw='git diff --word-diff'
gf='git fetch'
gfa='git fetch --all --prune'
gfg='git ls-files | grep'
gfo='git fetch origin'
gg='git gui citool'
gga='git gui citool --amend'
ggpull='git pull origin "$(git_current_branch)"'
ggpush='git push origin "$(git_current_branch)"'
ggsup='git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/$(git_current_branch)'
ghh='git help'
gignore='git update-index --assume-unchanged'
gignored='git ls-files -v | grep "^[[:lower:]]"'
git-svn-dcommit-push='git svn dcommit && git push github master:svntrunk'
gk='\gitk --all --branches'
gke='\gitk --all $(git log -g --pretty=%h)'
gl='git pull'
glg='git log --stat'
glgg='git log --graph'
glgga='git log --graph --decorate --all'
glgm='git log --graph --max-count=10'
glgp='git log --stat -p'
glo='git log --oneline --decorate'
glod='git log --graph --pretty='\''%Cred%h%Creset -%C(auto)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%ad) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'\'
glods='git log --graph --pretty='\''%Cred%h%Creset -%C(auto)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%ad) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'\'' --date=short'
glog='git log --oneline --decorate --graph'
gloga='git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all'
glol='git log --graph --pretty='\''%Cred%h%Creset -%C(auto)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'\'
glola='git log --graph --pretty='\''%Cred%h%Creset -%C(auto)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'\'' --all'
glols='git log --graph --pretty='\''%Cred%h%Creset -%C(auto)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'\'' --stat'
glp=_git_log_prettily
glum='git pull upstream master'
gm='git merge'
gma='git merge --abort'
gmom='git merge origin/master'
gmt='git mergetool --no-prompt'
gmtvim='git mergetool --no-prompt --tool=vimdiff'
gmum='git merge upstream/master'
gp='git push'
gpd='git push --dry-run'
gpf='git push --force-with-lease'
'gpf!'='git push --force'
gpoat='git push origin --all && git push origin --tags'
gpristine='git reset --hard && git clean -dfx'
gpsup='git push --set-upstream origin $(git_current_branch)'
gpu='git push upstream'
gpv='git push -v'
gr='git remote'
gra='git remote add'
grb='git rebase'
grba='git rebase --abort'
grbc='git rebase --continue'
grbd='git rebase develop'
grbi='git rebase -i'
grbm='git rebase master'
grbs='git rebase --skip'
grev='git revert'
grh='git reset'
grhh='git reset --hard'
grm='git rm'
grmc='git rm --cached'
grmv='git remote rename'
groh='git reset origin/$(git_current_branch) --hard'
grrm='git remote remove'
grs='git restore'
grset='git remote set-url'
grss='git restore --source'
grt='cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel || echo .)"'
gru='git reset --'
grup='git remote update'
grv='git remote -v'
gsb='git status -sb'
gsd='git svn dcommit'
gsh='git show'
gsi='git submodule init'
gsps='git show --pretty=short --show-signature'
gsr='git svn rebase'
gss='git status -s'
gst='git status'
gsta='git stash push'
gstaa='git stash apply'
gstall='git stash --all'
gstc='git stash clear'
gstd='git stash drop'
gstl='git stash list'
gstp='git stash pop'
gsts='git stash show --text'
gsu='git submodule update'
gsw='git switch'
gswc='git switch -c'
gtl='gtl(){ git tag --sort=-v:refname -n -l "${1}*" }; noglob gtl'
gts='git tag -s'
gtv='git tag | sort -V'
gunignore='git update-index --no-assume-unchanged'
gunwip='git log -n 1 | grep -q -c "\-\-wip\-\-" && git reset HEAD~1'
gup='git pull --rebase'
gupa='git pull --rebase --autostash'
gupav='git pull --rebase --autostash -v'
gupv='git pull --rebase -v'
gwch='git whatchanged -p --abbrev-commit --pretty=medium'
gwip='git add -A; git rm $(git ls-files --deleted) 2> /dev/null; git commit --no-verify --no-gpg-sign -m "--wip-- [skip ci]"'
```

Comment: Do you have any aliases defined? Try running `alias | grep git` and report the results back here.

Comment: If you run `git log` with no additional arguments, Git starts at the commit you have checked out now, and works backwards. If you have a historical commit checked out, that's what you will see: that commit, and then earlier commits, going backwards. Run `git log master` to view from the commit labeled `master` backwards; run `git checkout master` to make the tip commit of `master` your current commit, and `git log` will start from that commit and work backwards.

Comment: This would, however, apply only to each individual repository. If it is happening on all of them, you probably are running some other command than the normal `git log`. Check for a script named `git-log` in your `$PATH`.

Comment: @Mureinik: Good idea. Edited my question. There are a lot of them because of oh-my-zsh.

Comment: @RaYokai can you please paste the result here instead of in an external link?

Comment: @torek: Absolutely, that makes sense. It is indeed happening to all of my repos and I tried on master as well. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to git log in reverse order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798822/how-to-git-log-in-reverse-order)

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you update the latest source code.

```
git fetch --all
```

If you use `git log` with no argument, you get only the latest commit of branch where you are. You could view all commits of a specified branch `git log branch_name` or you could use `git log --all`to view all commits of repository.

Comment: Thanks! Well I've tried with a freshly cloned repo using master. This is just a weird situation that's possibly caused by something really simple :)