# How do I expand a built in Git command with an alias?

Tags: git, alias

When answering "[Git pull hook script which executes locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207749/git-pull-hook-script-which-executes-locally)", I stumbled upon the use-case to alias a built-in git command such as `pull` or `push` with an extension. How do I do that?

First thought was:

```
[alias]
    push = "!echo -n \"really push? [y/n]\";read -s -n 1 really;if [[ $really == \"y\" ]];then git push; else echo \"aborting\"; fi"
```

This works fine as long as I don't name my alias `push` (for example `qp` or something like that). But as soon as I call it `push`, it's somehow ignored.

Is there a git way to expand a built in git command with an alias or do I have to set up an alias in my `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: **you can't**.

Git disallows this explicitly to prevent confusion and shadowing that might affect the invocation of git commands (in scripts, etc.). See the **[git-config manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)**.

> `alias.*`
>
> Command aliases for the git(1) command wrapper - e.g. after defining "alias.last = cat-file commit HEAD", the invocation "git last" is equivalent to "git cat-file commit HEAD". To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, **aliases that hide existing git commands are ignored**. Arguments are split by spaces, the usual shell quoting and escaping is supported. quote pair and a backslash can be used to quote them.

You could, as you noted, just name your alias something else and use that instead, or do it in `bash`. However, note that multiword aliases in bash are not possible, so you can't have an alias for "git push". Instead you'll need to use a function -- see "[Bash: Spaces in alias name](https://superuser.com/questions/105375/bash-spaces-in-alias-name)" on SuperUser for some hints (you can probably adopt it wholesale).