# Default number of commits for Git log

Tags: git

Is there any way to configure the default number of commits that will be returned by git log?  I know you can do `git log -5` to get the last 5 commits, but what if I forget and just do `git log`?  I have several aliases for `git log` and would like them all to return something like the last 100 commits unless I specify something else specifically.

Ideal situation assuming I have `git ls` setup as an alias:

`git ls` returns the last 100

`git ls -5` returns the last 5

It would be really great if I could to something like `git ls -0` to disable the default and return everything.

Is any of this possible or should I consider this my first draft for a feature request to the Git team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you supply more than one count, the last one takes precedence. For example, `git log -2 -1` shows only one result.

So you can supply a default parameter in your alias definition and optionally override it when you run the command.

Regarding using `-0` to return everything, just use `-9999999` or similar instead.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this recently, I tried to do what the accepted answer says but can't get it to work, and found a more recent answer saying you can't name an alias after a built-in git command anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11226146/14587004.

For anyone wondering how to get close enough, I did

`git config --global alias.ls 'log -100'`

to get the `git ls` alias to work how the OP puts it. I also added the `--oneline` flag to mine, which I think is nice to know about. The git config command edits the `~/.gitconfig` file, so you can edit it manually with a text editor too if you want. You would append

```
[alias]
    ls = log -5
```

to the file.