# Git aliases with linux commands

Tags: git

Basically I want to compare a local file in the current branch against the remote file, but also I would like to know if there is a way to mix Git aliases with Linux commands.

The script I created looks like this:

```
git show origin/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD):$1 > /tmp/xxx <br/>
git diff /tmp/xxx $1
```

Is there a way to do that as a Git alias instead of having to create scripts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2554167/4361073

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alias will be passed to the shell for execution if the value begins with the
`!` character. So it is possible to define an alias to do what you want.

```
[alias]
    diff-remote = "!f() { git show origin/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD):$GIT_PREFIX$1 > /tmp/xxx; git diff /tmp/xxx $GIT_PREFIX$1; }; f"
```

Aliases are always run from the top directory of the repository, with the path
from there to the original directory stored in `$GIT_PREFIX`.  So it is
necessary to prepend that to file names in order for an alias to work from
other directories within the repository.

But, to do that it is necessary to put the actual code into a function.
Otherwise there is no way for that variable to be inserted immediately before
the first argument.

So this alias definition defines a shell function (named `f`) with the desired
commands and then immediately runs that.  There's no need to cleanup the
temporary function because that shell will be exiting right after the function
does.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in the shell, rather than git itself. Either write a script and save it in your path, or write it as a shell function:

```
function diff-remote()
{
    git show "origin/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD):$1" > /tmp/diff-remote.$$
    git diff /tmp/diff-remote.$$ "$1"
    rm /tmp/diff-remote.$$
}
```

you can type that on the command line, save it to a file and source it, or add it directly to your `.bashrc`.

Just type `diff-remote myfile` to use.

Answer (score 0):

Since `git` aliases can't take arguments (e.g. `$1`), there's probably no way to do this directly with aliases. There are a couple other alternatives, though:

1. Create a script `some_script` and set up a `git` alias that calls that script, or
2. Name the script `git-something`, make sure it's in your `PATH`, and then you can use it as `git something`, or
3. Just use the script outside of `git`.

In this case, however, I think you should be able to `git diff origin/master:file master:file`. That skips the `rev-parse` bit, so it won't automatically sort out which remote branch to use, and thus requires a little more mental effort to know what is upstream of your current local branch, but in most cases, that shouldn't be to strenuous...