# git alias command is not working can any one describe me syntax of git alias command

Tags: git, alias

git alias command is not working
I tried 
`git alias'cm' commit -m`
but this is not working for me.

Comment: This post answers your question well.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553786/how-do-i-alias-commands-in-git

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#set the alias
git config --global alias.cm "commit -m"
```

#### Using it:

```
git cm "message"
```

Comment: this is working.
thanks

Comment: Cool, if its working you should accept the answer