# Add new command on Windows Git Bash

Tags: windows, git, addition, commit

I would like to add new command on my Git Bash (just now i am under Windows OS). I tryed to look on Web different solutions but I did not find anything. The command that i like to add is:

> commitall -> git add --all && git commit -m "$*"

There is a way to add this command on Windows Git Bash?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git alias command is not working can any one describe me syntax of git alias command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788557/git-alias-command-is-not-working-can-any-one-describe-me-syntax-of-git-alias-com)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I alias commands in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553786/how-do-i-alias-commands-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Git aliases](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases), like so:

```
git config --global alias.commitall '!git add --all && git commit -m'
```

There's no need to use `$*` because all the arguments you specify will simply be appended to the line above, i.e. if you run:

```
git comitall "a message"
```

…the following will be executed:

```
git add --all && git commit -m "a message"
```