# How to rename git commands

Tags: git, command-line, command, rename

I would like to rename the following git commands:

Instead of typing:

- `git checkout` I would like to rename it to `git co`.
- `git commit` I would like to rename it to `git cm`.
- `git push origin` I would like to rename it to `git po`.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I alias commands in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553786/how-do-i-alias-commands-in-git)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chapter "[Git Aliases](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases)" in the [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) book shows exactly what you need:

```
git config --global alias.co checkout
git config --global alias.cm commit
git config --global alias.po 'push origin'
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is creating so called 'aliases' for your $shell (bash/csh/zsh/fish).

Try this excellent blog post from well known david walsh:
https://davidwalsh.name/alias-bash

But be careful:
non-standard aliases will break your mind when working on a remote machine via ssh or when switching machines, and if you use your aliases in scripts they won't run elsewhere!

Answer (score 1):

Use aliases : [here is a link showing how does it work](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-permanent-bash-alias-linux-unix/).

You can put something like this in your `.bash_profile` file:

```
alias checkout='git checkout'
alias pull='git pull'
alias push='git push origin'
alias push_f='git push origin -f'
alias rebase='git rebase'
#...
```

and then `source .bash_profile`

Now you can write : 
`checkout master`, `push master`, `checkout master`

Be carefull: you cannot put arguments when you declare aliases.

Comment: Please include the appropriate text in the answer. Links rot, please don't rely on them.