# Git alias to squash feature-branch commits

Tags: git, git-merge, git-squash, git-alias

I'm frequently squashing all the commits on a feature branch before committing to master. Here's what I do currently:

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash {branch}
git commit -m "{feature_summary}"
```

Is there an git alias I can use to do this? The aliases I'm familiar with (e.g. `stashes = stash list` or `uncommit = reset --soft HEAD~1`)  don't store variables, and in this case the second command needs to know which branch we *came from* at the beginning of the commands, so I imagine has to store this information.

Ideally I'd like a git alias such as `git squash` which does all those commands. I'm fine with either expecting a string as the commit message, or opening an editor to enter the message.

Comment: xargs can be used for that. 
However, I am too bad at its syntax, so I'm just commenting, not answering. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@{-1}` construct which means "last checked out branch", and pass a parameter to an ad-hoc bash function :

```
# ms for merge-squash but call it as you prefer
git config --global alias.ms '!f() { git checkout master && git merge --squash @{-1} && git commit -m "$1"; }; f'
```

then an example use could be, from your feature branch :

```
git ms "My commit message"
```

Comment: @msanford Ha! Glad to see you here too.

Comment: This looks perfect, but I'm getting `fatal: bad alias.squash-master string: unclosed quote` based on `squash-master  = '!f() { git checkout master && git merge --squash @{-1} && git commit -m "$1"; }; f `

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Maximilian Strange... checking at the moment, I'll edit as soon as I know.

Comment: I think it was a quote issue in the shell command vs adding to a file. I cut out the function and so this works now and is possibly more compressed? `squash-master  = "!git checkout master && git merge --squash @{-1} && git commit -m"`

Answer (score 1):

You can [create an alias yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2553799/114900):

```
[alias]
    sf = !git checkout master && git merge --squash "$1" && git commit -m "$2"
```

You can run it with

```
git sf <branch> "<message>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have in your `PATH` a program called `git-command`, `git` will use that program when you call `git command [args]`.

So you can add the following script to your PATH, name it `git-squash` and make it executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
branch="${1}"
shift
git checkout master \
&& git merge --squash "${branch}" \
&& git commit "${@}"
```