# How to tell git --ignore-space-at-eol globally, everytime, once for all?

Tags: git, git-diff

I'm tired of changing `core.autocrlf` to `true`, `input` and `false` from time to time in order to make `git diff` ignore `CRLF` and `LF` differences. At this time `git diff` does not even display an `^M` character at the diff output, but still behaves like the files are fully different while they are fully same.

I came across `git diff --ignore-space-at-eol` switch, which fixes my issue. I am, however, not able to configure this behavior globally.

How can I tell `git diff` to use `--ignore-space-at-eol` switch by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I tell git diff to use --ignore-space-at-eol switch by default?

You can't.

You *can*, however, set up an *alias* or, or write your own command, that invokes `git diff` and adds the flag.  That's probably the way to go here.  See, e.g., [How do I alias commands in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2553786/1256452)