# How has this shortcut for `git add -all` been made (in Terminal)?

Tags: git, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have a shortcut that was added to my computer in Terminal. (I use `zsh`). Instead of having to type `git add -all` I can type `gaa`. My question is:

Any ideas where/how this shortcut made? How can I see exactly what command it is short for and how do I change it?

After following these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553786/how-do-i-alias-commands-in-git), I thought I'd be able to see it in `~/.gitconfig` but it's not there. It doesn't look like it's in `~/.zshrc` either:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `type gaa` in your terminal

Comment: @JoshAbraham Thanks. Now just to find how this was made and how to delete it

Comment: @tonitone120 : Well, what did `type gaa` say?

Comment: `git add --all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re using [Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/), which adds a bunch of [aliases](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Cheatsheet).

You’re most likely loading their file in your `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Thanks for the response @JBaillin. Unfortunately, it's not in there.

Comment: The exact definition is in a file source, either directly or indirectly, by `.zshrc` (or possibly `.zprofile`).

Comment: @tonitone120 it's in your zshrc. Look at line 3. Line 1 is where you're enabling the git plugin.

Comment: @JBallin What is line3? What's the meaning of it? Bear in mind my goal's still to delete this shortcut (and add others)

Comment: I'm referring to line 3 in the image you shared of zshrc (`source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`). You can uninstall oh my zsh by following these [instructions](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/#uninstalling-oh-my-zsh). You can also disable the git plugin (delete line 1 - `plugins=(git)`) or just overwrite their aliases with your own. Line 3 is loading (source) the file (path to file).

Comment: So is there a folder called `ZSH`? And if so, where? I'm not so much as looking to remove the oh-my-zsh so much as just see what shortcuts are being made and alter them - if that were possible

Comment: `$ZSH` is a variable that you're defining in the top image. I don't recommend altering their existing aliases. You can just make your own `alias gaa="git add --all"` (you have one at the bottom of your `zshrc` already).

Comment: Okay, well thanks for your answer showing me these shortcuts come from oh-my-zsh (if I've understood you correctly) and pointing out I can overwrite them with aliases at the bottom of my `.oh-my-zsh` file.

Comment: @tonitone120 you should use your zshrc. That's your personal file to configure your zsh (you can google "dotfiles" to find examples). Files belonging to oh my zsh may get changed by updates etc., I wouldn't recommend altering those.

Comment: Yes sorry meant to say 'I can overwrite them with aliases at the bottom of my `.zshrc` file