# What's the difference between git clone --mirror and git clone --bare

Tags: git, git-clone

The git clone help page has this to say about `--mirror`:

> Set up a mirror of the remote repository. This implies `--bare`.

But doesn't go into detail about how the `--mirror` clone is different from a `--bare` clone.

Comment: helpful, but if you also want to push this mirror to a remote repo like github, I found [this link](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository#mirroring-a-repository) handy.

Answer (score 785, accepted):

The difference is that when using `--mirror`, *all* refs are copied *as-is*. This means everything: remote-tracking branches, notes, refs/originals/* (backups from filter-branch). The cloned repo has it all. It's also set up so that a remote update will re-fetch everything from the origin (overwriting the copied refs). The idea is really to mirror the repository, to have a total copy, so that you could for example host your central repo in multiple places, or back it up. Think of just straight-up copying the repo, except in a much more elegant git way.

The new [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---mirror) pretty much says all this:

> `--mirror`
>
> Set up a mirror of the source repository.  This implies `--bare`. Compared to `--bare`, `--mirror` not only maps local branches of the source to local branches of the target, it maps all refs (including remote branches, notes etc.) and sets up a refspec configuration such that all these refs are overwritten by a `git remote update` in the target repository.

My original answer also noted the differences between a bare clone and a normal (non-bare) clone - the non-bare clone sets up remote tracking branches, only creating a local branch for `HEAD`, while the bare clone copies the branches directly.

Suppose origin has a few branches (`master (HEAD)`, `next`, `pu`, and `maint`), some tags (`v1`, `v2`, `v3`), some remote branches (`devA/master`, `devB/master`), and some other refs (`refs/foo/bar`, `refs/foo/baz`, which might be notes, stashes, other devs' namespaces, who knows).

- **`git clone origin-url` (non-bare):** You will get all of the tags copied, a local branch `master (HEAD)` tracking a remote branch `origin/master`, and remote branches `origin/next`, `origin/pu`, and `origin/maint`. The tracking branches are set up so that if you do something like `git fetch origin`, they'll be fetched as you expect. Any remote branches (in the cloned remote) and other refs are completely ignored.
- **`git clone --bare origin-url`:** You will get all of the tags copied, local branches `master (HEAD)`, `next`, `pu`, and `maint`, no remote tracking branches. That is, all branches are copied as is, and it's set up completely independent, with no expectation of fetching again. Any remote branches (in the cloned remote) and other refs are completely ignored.
- **`git clone --mirror origin-url`:** Every last one of those refs will be copied as-is. You'll get all the tags, local branches `master (HEAD)`, `next`, `pu`, and `maint`, remote branches `devA/master` and `devB/master`, other refs `refs/foo/bar` and `refs/foo/baz`. Everything is exactly as it was in the cloned remote. Remote tracking is set up so that if you run `git remote update` all refs will be overwritten from origin, as if you'd just deleted the mirror and recloned it. As the docs originally said, it's a mirror. It's supposed to be a functionally identical copy, interchangeable with the original.

Comment: Does "normal clone" refer to a clone without the --bare or --mirror flags?

Comment: Yeah, it does. With a bare clone, as it says on the man page, branches are copied directly as well (no refs/remotes/origin, no tracking). Edited in.

Comment: Can you add some more usage example about the difference, not just the git-internal differences?

Comment: @Casey is that what you were looking for? I didn't think what I originally wrote was "internal" at all - tags and branches are very much porcelain features.

Comment: Does "branches copied as is" mean that branches are copied to the same relative path on the clone? Or does it imply that branches are transformed in some way?

Comment: You said "...and remote branches origin/next, origin/pu, and origin/maint" in `git clone origin-url` section and then said "Any remote branches" are ignored. How's that?

Comment: @Cascabel Lets say I am working in a team of 5 member. So, when I did `git clone --mirror origin-url`, does it give local branches of other team members local repository?

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik You'll get whatever's in the repo you're cloning. If they've all pushed all their branches to it, you'll get them; if they haven't, you won't. If you clone one of their local repos directly, you'll get everything in it.

Comment: @Cascabel so clear explanation. just one doubt: what do you mean when you say "other refs `refs/foo/bar` and `refs/foo/baz`". What kind of refs  are you talking about. I understood the tags, local branch, remote branch part. But what is this "other refs" thing?

Comment: Great answer. What about submodules? Do those count as "other refs"?

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick if you research how to archive git branches, you'll discover an archiving mechanism that directly creates refs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41008657/565877

Comment: @Cascabel your answer is well written, just being curious if you can add other set of bullets points indicating when take each approach, it mostly for the `--mirror`, because in this network (SO) already exists many posts about differences and when use `non bare` vs `bare`

Comment: "all refs will be overwritten from origin, as if you'd just deleted the mirror and recloned it." so it will download everything from scratch without leveraging git's functionality of fetching just the difference?

Comment: To clarify: this does *not* include stashes - though are hacks to copy stashes, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550378/is-it-possible-to-push-a-git-stash-to-a-remote-repository

Answer (score 97):

```
$ git clone --mirror $URL
```

is a short-hand for

```
$ git clone --bare $URL
$ (cd $(basename $URL) && git remote add --mirror=fetch origin $URL)
```

(Copied directly from [here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-1-2-clone-Add-an-option-to-set-up-a-mirror-tp664305.html))

How the current man-page puts it:

> Compared to `--bare`, `--mirror` not only maps local branches of the source to local branches of the target, it maps all refs (including remote branches, notes etc.) and sets up a refspec configuration such that all these refs are overwritten by a `git remote update` in the target repository.

Comment: I believe you'd have to follow that with a `git fetch` for it to actually be identical. Anyway, this is sort of a non-answer - the point of the question is "how is a mirror remote/clone different from a normal one?"

Comment: I actually like this way of demonstrating the difference.  Hopefully it is accurate!  I hope hfs adds the fetch command.

Comment: not really clear, e.g. what is $(basename $URL) translating into, etc.

Comment: `basename` is the normal unix utility that strips the directory part of a path, and `$()` is simply bash's command substitution.

Comment: This still has `--mirror` in it.  This would only be an acceptable answer if it explained what `git remote add --mirror` does.

Answer (score 31):

I add a picture, show `config`difference between mirror and bare.
[image]
The left is bare, right is mirror. You can be clear, mirror's config file have `fetch` key, which means you can update it, by `git remote update` or `git fetch --all`

Answer (score 28):

My tests with git-2.0.0 today indicate that the --mirror option does not copy hooks, the config file, the description file, the info/exclude file, and at least in my test case a few refs (which I don't understand.) I would not call it a "functionally identical copy, interchangeable with the original."

```
-bash-3.2$ git --version
git version 2.0.0
-bash-3.2$ git clone --mirror /git/hooks
Cloning into bare repository 'hooks.git'...
done.

-bash-3.2$ diff --brief -r /git/hooks.git hooks.git
Files /git/hooks.git/config and hooks.git/config differ
Files /git/hooks.git/description and hooks.git/description differ
...
Only in hooks.git/hooks: applypatch-msg.sample
...
Only in /git/hooks.git/hooks: post-receive
...
Files /git/hooks.git/info/exclude and hooks.git/info/exclude differ
...
Files /git/hooks.git/packed-refs and hooks.git/packed-refs differ
Only in /git/hooks.git/refs/heads: fake_branch
Only in /git/hooks.git/refs/heads: master
Only in /git/hooks.git/refs: meta
```

Answer (score 20):

A nuanced explanation from the GitHub documentation on [Duplicating a Repository](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/):

> As with a bare clone, a mirrored clone includes all remote branches and tags, but all local references will be overwritten each time you fetch, so it will always be the same as the original repository.

Comment: Thank you; this clarified for me that local *tags* will be overwritten as well as branches by using a mirrored clone.  Very helpful.

Comment: You might also want to use `--prune` when running git fetch to remove local references that are no longer on the remote.

Answer (score 18):

A clone copies the refs from the remote and stuffs them into a subdirectory named 'these are the refs that the remote has'.

A mirror copies the refs from the remote and puts them into its own top level - it replaces its own refs with those of the remote.

This means that when someone pulls from your mirror and stuffs the mirror's refs into thier subdirectory, they will get the same refs as were on the original. The result of fetching from an up-to-date mirror is the same as fetching directly from the initial repo.

Answer (score 14):

Unlike `git clone`, `git clone --mirror` and `git clone --bare` both are bare repos. The difference between them are in the `config` file.

`git clone`'s config file looks like:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/example
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

`git clone --bare`'s config file looks like:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/example
```

`git clone --mirror`'s config file looks like:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/example
    fetch = +refs/*:refs/*
    mirror = true
```

So, we see that the main difference in in the [refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) to be used for fetching

> The format of the refspec is, first, an optional `+`, followed by
> `<src>:<dst>`, where `<src>` is the pattern for references on the
> remote side and `<dst>` is where those references will be tracked
> locally. The `+` tells Git to update the reference even if it isn’t a
> fast-forward.

In case of `git clone` that is automatically written by a `git remote add origin` command, Git fetches all the references under `refs/heads/` on the server and writes them to `refs/remotes/origin/` locally.

In case of `git clone --bare`, there is no refspec to be used for fetching.

In case of `git clone --mirror`, the refspec to be used for fetching looks like `fetch = +refs/*:refs/*`. It means, `tags`, `remotes`, `replace` (which is under `refs` directory) along with `heads` will be fetched as well. Note that, **by default `git clone` only fetch `heads`**.

**NOTE 1:** `git clone --mirror` and `git clone --bare --mirror` are equivalent.

**NOTE 2:** there is also difference in [`packed-refs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout). As it records the same information as `refs/heads/`, `refs/tags/`, and friends record in a more efficient way.

Comment: Important detail about config difference what @Cascabel have had missed to point out.

Answer (score 9):

```
$ git clone --bare https://github.com/example
```

This command will make the new "`example`" directory itself the $GIT_DIR (instead of `example/.git`). Also the branch heads at the remote are copied directly to corresponding local branch heads, without mapping. When this option is used, neither remote-tracking branches nor the related configuration variables are created.

```
$ git clone --mirror https://github.com/example
```

As with a bare clone, a mirrored clone includes all remote branches and tags, but all local references (including remote-tracking branches, notes etc.) will be overwritten each time you fetch, so it will always be the same as the original repository.

Answer (score 0):

> As with a bare clone, a mirrored clone includes all remote branches and tags, but all local references will be overwritten each time you fetch, so it will always be the same as the original repository. Setting the URL for pushes simplifies pushing to your mirror.

ref: [Duplicating a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository)