# Get log of untracked branch

Tags: git

So, the simplest way to ask my question, as far as I can tell, is to specify my use-case. At the end of the day, when I write in my journal, I want to be able to see what I have done that day. So I `fetch` changes from work and then look at the log to remember what I did. The problem here is that even though clones allegedly [contain everything important](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4658547/1366594), I cannot for the life of me get the log entries of newer commits without checking out the branch in question and possibly doing a fast-forward. This can be done with SourceTree and TortoiseGit, but I use Linux, and all of the tools I have tried have the same issue as the stock `git log --all` command that doesn't list the new commits that I know are there. How can I do this WITHOUT checking out all of the branches that may have new commits?

Edit: since giving replies in a comment is limited, I will do it here.

- I am currently using a bare repo with worktrees around it. Don't think that would cause issues, but I am including that anyway. The format is
- -Code
- ---Code.git
- ---master
- `git branch -r` outputs nothing when in `Code.git` and `master`. It gives a "not a git repo" error in `Code`
- `git fetch --all` indicates that it is fetching and receiving objects. It also completes successfully.
- `git remote -vv` outputs the origin remote for push and fetch
- `git ls-remote origin` shows all refs and branches on the remote
- `Code.git/packed-refs` contains a list of refs for heads and tags for the remote
- `find Code.git/refs` outputs:

```
refs/
refs/heads
refs/heads/master
refs/tags
```

Comment: `git log --all` definitely shows all commits. Maybe not in the order in which you expect them, but it shows all commits.

Comment: What is your working directory when you run `git branch -r`? Try running it in `Code`, in `Code.git`, and in `master`. Kindly provide the output from each directory.

Comment: But it sounds like "worktrees" is the magic word here which was missing from the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To view commits of remote-tracking branches specify their name (assuming a remote named `origin`; which is the default):

```
git log origin/branch1 origin/branch2
```

If only interested in new commits on a branch since your current commit:

```
git log HEAD..origin/branch1
```

If you want to view all history excluding a specific commit, you can use negative refs:

```
git log --all ^HEAD
# or more explicit:
git log --all --not HEAD
```

---

Make sure that your remotes are configured correctly. They must contain a `fetch` option in the `.git/config` file, otherwise no remote-tracking branches will be created nor updated in your repository. Usually, a remote block in the config file looks like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Specifying things like that gives me something like `fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/bug52339': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: @BrainStorm.exe but all remote branches have been fetched successfully? What branches are shown when you run `git branch -r`?

Comment: Nothing... Even after a `git fetch --all`. And, yes, the fetch did succeed.

Comment: @BrainStorm.exe `git branch -r` outputs nothing? Are you sure a) your repository is a clone (`git fetch --all` outputs nothing for non-clones) b) you have a remote configured `git remote -vv` c) the remote contains branches `git ls-remote origin` d) the fetch really succeeded (printing something like "Receiving objects"? Do you see the remote branches in `.git/packed-refs` or in `.git/refs/remotes/*/`?

Comment: Updated question with answers

Comment: Updated the `git branch -r` item. Sorry I didn't have "worktrees" in the original question.

Comment: @BrainStorm.exe Please run `git branch -r` in one of your worktrees and in the bare repo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230109/discussion-between-brainstorm-exe-and-knittl).