# Bundle git repository without cloning it

Tags: git, bundle, git-bundle

How can I bundle a git project without cloning it every time? Right now I do always commands below.

```
git clone --mirror http://git_project
cd git_project
git bundle create '../git_project.lock' --all
cd ..
rm git_project -Force -Recurse
```

I want to do this in one command, something like:

```
git bundle create '../git_project.lock' --all --repository http://git_project
```

Comment: No way — `git bundle` works only with local repository. Why do clone the project every time? Clone it once and update later with `git fetch/pull`. Improve by using bare repo.

Comment: @phd: I'll to got these bundle files as a backup on an other machine. like on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578270/fully-backup-a-git-repo#answer-5578292

Comment: Then run `git bundle` on that other machine.

Comment: @phd: It's in the cloud... We don't have access to that machine...

Comment: Then local clone is your only option. But you don't need to clone every time. Clone once, preserve the clone, and then update it with `git fetch/pull`. Create backup bundles from the clone as usual.

Comment: @phd: But when you don't remove your repository, `git bundle create` has no sense at all. I'll think about it what's the best thing. Thanks for the info @phd :)

Answer (score 1):

> I'll to got these bundle files as a backup on an other machine

Since my 2011 answer (eleven years ago), you now have remote pipelines like [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) or [GitLab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/).

An automated pipeline on those remote Git repository hosting services can create a bundle for you and save it to a server/backup.

That is today.

---

Tomorrow, you will be able to a "*git bundle*"-dedicated server, accessible through a **bundle URI**.

With Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), the "bundle URI" design gets documented.

See [commit d06ed85](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d06ed85dcbfa3eaf083a5fa5324670d049117bea), [commit 2da14fa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2da14fad8fe9889f067da2abe3b0763acae1f8f9) (09 Aug 2022) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0d133a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d133a3dcf43eb0396a5899008a4ff4ceaeb0d6e), 18 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`docs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2da14fad8fe9889f067da2abe3b0763acae1f8f9): document bundle URI standard
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> Introduce the idea of bundle URIs to the Git codebase through an aspirational design document.
> This document includes the full design intended to include the feature in its fully-implemented form.
> This will take several steps as detailed in the Implementation Plan section.
>
> By committing this document now, it can be used to motivate changes necessary to reach these final goals.
> The design can still be altered as new information is discovered.

`technical/bundle-uri` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2da14fad8fe9889f067da2abe3b0763acae1f8f9/Documentation/technical/bundle-uri.txt#L1-L468):

> ## Bundle URIs
>
> Git bundles are files that store a pack-file along with some extra metadata,
> including a set of refs and a (possibly empty) set of necessary commits. See
> [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) and link:bundle-format.txt[the bundle format] for more
> information.
>
> Bundle URIs are locations where Git can download one or more bundles in
> order to bootstrap the object database in advance of fetching the remaining
> objects from a remote.
>
> One goal is to speed up clones and fetches for users with poor network
> connectivity to the origin server. Another benefit is to allow heavy users,
> such as CI build farms, to use local resources for the majority of Git data
> and thereby reducing the load on the origin server.
>
> To enable the bundle URI feature, users can specify a bundle URI using
> command-line options or the origin server can advertise one or more URIs
> via a protocol v2 capability.

> ### See Also
>
> - [An earlier RFC for a bundle URI feature](https://lore.kernel.org/git/RFC-cover-00.13-0000000000-20210805T150534Z-avarab@gmail.com/).
> - The [GVFS Protocol](https://github.com/microsoft/VFSForGit/blob/master/Protocol.md)

And:

> ### [`bundle-uri`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d06ed85dcbfa3eaf083a5fa5324670d049117bea): add example bundle organization
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> Add a section that details how a bundle provider could work, including using the Git server advertisement for multiple geo-distributed servers.
> This organization is based on the GVFS Cache Servers which have successfully used similar ideas to provide fast object access and reduced server load for very large repositories.

`technical/bundle-uri` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d06ed85dcbfa3eaf083a5fa5324670d049117bea/Documentation/technical/bundle-uri.txt#L352-L456):

> ### Example Bundle Provider organization
>
> This example organization is a simplified model of what is used by the
> GVFS Cache Servers (see section near the end of this document) which have
> been beneficial in speeding up clones and fetches for very large
> repositories, although using extra software outside of Git.
>
> The bundle provider deploys servers across multiple geographies.
> Each server manages its own bundle set.
>
> The server can track a number of Git repositories, but provides a bundle list for each based on a pattern.
>
> For example, when mirroring a repository at `https://<domain>/<org>/<repo>`
> the bundle server could have its bundle list available at
> `https://<server-url>/<domain>/<org>/<repo>`.
> The origin Git server can
> list all of these servers under the "any" mode:
>
> ```ini
> [bundle]
> version = 1
> mode = any
>
> [bundle "eastus"]
> uri = https://eastus.example.com/<domain>/<org>/<repo>
>
> [bundle "europe"]
> uri = https://europe.example.com/<domain>/<org>/<repo>
>
> [bundle "apac"]
> uri = https://apac.example.com/<domain>/<org>/<repo>
> ```
>
> This "list of lists" is static and only changes if a bundle server is
> added or removed.
>
> The bundle server runs regularly-scheduled updates for the bundle list,
> such as once a day.
> During this task, the server fetches the latest
> contents from the origin server and generates a bundle containing the
> objects reachable from the latest origin refs, but not contained in a
> previously-computed bundle.
> This bundle is added to the list, with care
> that the `creationToken` is strictly greater than the previous maximum
> `creationToken`.
>
> An example bundle list is provided here, although it only has two daily
> bundles and not a full list of 30:
>
> ```ini
> [bundle]
> version = 1
> mode = all
> heuristic = creationToken
>
> [bundle "2022-02-13-1644770820-daily"]
> uri = https://eastus.example.com/<domain>/<org>/<repo>/2022-02-09-1644770820-daily.bundle
> creationToken = 1644770820
>
> [bundle "2022-02-09-1644442601-daily"]
> uri = https://eastus.example.com/<domain>/<org>/<repo>/2022-02-09-1644442601-daily.bundle
> creationToken = 1644442601
>
> [bundle "2022-02-02-1643842562"]
> uri = https://eastus.example.com/<domain>/<org>/<repo>/2022-02-02-1643842562.bundle
> creationToken = 1643842562
> ```
>
> The intention of this data organization has two main goals.
>
> - First, initial
>   clones of the repository become faster by downloading precomputed object
>   data from a closer source.
> - Second, `git fetch` commands can be faster,
>   especially if the client has not fetched for a few days. However, if a
>   client does not fetch for 30 days, then the bundle list organization would
>   cause redownloading a large amount of object data.

---

This is implemented (still with Git 2.38 (Q3 2022)): "[`git clone --bundle-uri`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/68ef0425d99cafb08f4c33eaa558505068fe2143/Documentation/git-clone.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone))</sup>.

See [commit 65da938](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65da93891680edc0d1471d436d92d4da7d0b4465) (23 Aug 2022), and [commit e21e663](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e21e663cd1942df29979d3e01f7eacb532727bb7), [commit 59c1752](https://github.com/git/git/commit/59c1752ab6768cb9c380f0a7c9d06af79d183f67), [commit 5556891](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55568919616429fbc209880cf189a3adaceb6093), [commit 53a5089](https://github.com/git/git/commit/53a50892be20a91fb0dcf572a641ce2a79af1a38), [commit b5624a4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5624a44744d6e5f9c749e4df02932c724e2097e) (09 Aug 2022) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 68ef042](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68ef0425d99cafb08f4c33eaa558505068fe2143), 01 Sep 2022)</sup>

> ### [`clone`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55568919616429fbc209880cf189a3adaceb6093): add --bundle-uri option
>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Josh Steadmon</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> Cloning a remote repository is one of the most expensive operations in Git.
> The server can spend a lot of CPU time generating a pack-file for the client's request.
> The amount of data can clog the network for a long time, and the Git protocol is not resumable.
> For users with poor network connections or are located far away from the origin server, this can be especially painful.
>
> Add a new '`--bundle-uri`' option to '[`git clone`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/55568919616429fbc209880cf189a3adaceb6093/Documentation/git-clone.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone))</sup> to bootstrap a clone from a bundle.
> If the user is aware of a bundle server, then they can tell Git to bootstrap the new repository with these bundles before fetching the remaining objects from the origin server.

`git clone` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/55568919616429fbc209880cf189a3adaceb6093/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L326-L331):

> ### `--bundle-uri=<uri>`
>
> Before fetching from the remote, fetch a bundle from the given
> `<uri>` and unbundle the data into the local repository.
>
> The refs
> in the bundle will be stored under the hidden `refs/bundle/*`
> namespace.
>
> This option is incompatible with `--depth`, `--shallow-since`, and `--shallow-exclude`

---

Git 2.39 (Q4 2022) defines the logical elements of a "`bundle list`", data structure to store them in-core, format to transfer them, and code to parse them.

See [commit 8628a84](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8628a842bddda7723ad7548b7f6d141123a164a0), [commit 70334fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70334fc3ebf1c6199014d82bbbf0595b64a8fa90), [commit 89bd7fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89bd7fedf947484da08e2722d663fdac23a431be), [commit c23f592](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c23f592117bac30765ca22545386c3e9304da803), [commit c96060b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c96060b0cef79c9d76eb97965e700beb9651f35b), [commit 20c1e2a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20c1e2a68bfcb85dd919c92a82c129cee215c23a), [commit 738e524](https://github.com/git/git/commit/738e5245fa423fc43495e2e17e053365dc6b2fc0), [commit bff03c4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bff03c47f7342c2a08fac6c0af7229b1579fea15), [commit 0634f71](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0634f717a3e3c57ee5d965882366df1ada1ad11b), [commit 23b6d00](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23b6d00ba7fd4b3446319395cfe3791710e81d92) (12 Oct 2022) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
See [commit d796ced](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d796cedbe8ca77310a7dabcafe60b040aa0e2b67), [commit 9424e37](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9424e373fd2136aa7f5cec23c8cafc272996ecd6) (12 Oct 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
See [commit f677f62](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f677f62970eed0f4b1a9075bcaf3f9f64027f30e) (24 Aug 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Taylor Blau -- `ttaylorr` --](https://github.com/ttaylorr) in [commit d32dd8a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d32dd8add53120cef9b30be4240010c2ab6bfc6f), 30 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`bundle-uri`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c23f592117bac30765ca22545386c3e9304da803): fetch a list of bundles
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> When the content at a given bundle URI is not understood as a bundle (based on inspecting the initial content), then Git currently gives up and ignores that content.
> Independent bundle providers may want to split up the bundle content into multiple bundles, but still make them available from a single URI.
>
> Teach Git to attempt parsing the bundle URI content as a Git config file providing the `key=value` pairs for a bundle list.
> Git then looks at the mode of the list to see if ANY single bundle is sufficient or if ALL bundles are required.
> The content at the selected URIs are downloaded and the content is inspected again, creating a recursive process.
>
> To guard the recursion against malformed or malicious content, limit the recursion depth to a reasonable four for now.
> This can be converted to a configured value in the future if necessary.
> The value of four is twice as high as expected to be useful (a bundle list is unlikely to point to more bundle lists).
>
> To test this scenario, create an interesting bundle topology where three incremental bundles are built on top of a single full bundle.
> By using a merge commit, the two middle bundles are "independent" in that they do not require each other in order to unbundle themselves.
> They each only need the base bundle.
> The bundle containing the merge commit requires both of the middle bundles, though.
> This leads to some interesting decisions when unbundling, especially when we later implement heuristics that promote downloading bundles until the prerequisite commits are satisfied.

---

Git 2.40 (Q1 2023) continues bundle URIs implementation (part 4).

See [commit 876094a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/876094ac16870727207e6afc0b26060101a52359), [commit 12b0a14](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12b0a14b9e5f140a9a4d5a3e3c47fae00a53c6fc), [commit ebc3947](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ebc39479558fb4893c72a35065e6792515acef86), [commit 9ea5796](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ea57964953dec11dcbbd5d4bf44a5e3781f5880), [commit 738dc7d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/738dc7d4a5f42376bc748008dd8792aa4eb25627), [commit 1b759e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b759e0cf1c18c637e40c6c191a0b614e4e4ea43) (22 Dec 2022) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
See [commit 70b9c10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70b9c1037325ee82bc0832f4ca2d30c6ebf4808e), [commit 7cce907](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7cce9074a728fb32501054577963d8ae31d007be), [commit 0cfde74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cfde740f0b2c9474aae3a381d1d6e97c7468e7a), [commit 8f788eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f788eb8b75502acb5c7d771279e486bae626dde), [commit 8b8d9a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b8d9a229888adb737851c4d7eeaa9a50e37afe1) (22 Dec 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0903d8b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0903d8bbdef6c2607f2e0bf43a4d10cf54b03744), 02 Jan 2023)</sup>

> ### [`bundle-uri client`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7cce9074a728fb32501054577963d8ae31d007be): add boolean `transfer.bundleURI` setting
>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The yet-to-be introduced client support for bundle-uri will always fall back on a full clone, but we'd still like to be able to ignore a server's bundle-uri advertisement entirely.
>
> The new `transfer.bundleURI` config option defaults to 'false', but a user can set it to 'true' to enable checking for bundle URIs from the origin Git server using protocol v2.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7cce9074a728fb32501054577963d8ae31d007be/Documentation/config/transfer.txt#L118-L123):

> ### `transfer.bundleURI`
>
> When `true`, local `git clone` commands will request bundle
> information from the remote server (if advertised) and download
> bundles before continuing the clone through the Git protocol.
> Defaults to `false`.

And:

> ### [`bundle-uri`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/738dc7d4a5f42376bc748008dd8792aa4eb25627): serve `bundle.* keys` from config
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> Implement the "bundle-uri" protocol v2 capability by populating the `key=value` packet lines from the local Git config.
> The list of bundles is provided from the keys beginning with "bundle.".

And:

> ### [`bundle-uri`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ebc39479558fb4893c72a35065e6792515acef86): allow relative URLs in bundle lists
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> Bundle providers may want to distribute that data across multiple CDNs.
> This might require a change in the base URI, all the way to the domain name.
> If all bundles require an absolute URI in their '`uri`' value, then every push to a CDN would require altering the table of contents to match the expected domain and exact location within it.
>
> **Allow a bundle list to specify a relative URI for the bundles**.
>
> This URI is based on where the client received the bundle list.
> For a list provided in the 'bundle-uri' protocol v2 command, the Git remote URI is the base URI.
> Otherwise, the bundle list was provided from an HTTP URI not using the Git protocol, and that URI is the base URI.
> This allows easier distribution of bundle data.

---

With Git 2.40 (Q1 2023), the bundle-URI subsystem adds support for creation-token heuristics to help incremental fetches.

See [commit 026df9e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/026df9e04789e2af7271566f312aae323740309f), [commit c429bed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c429bed10223135a13f1f2f854e367762c37af7a), [commit 7f0cc04](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f0cc04f2ca1653d573dbe981090895dc959ce65), [commit 0524ad3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0524ad3542c48c759366bc49dbd8bed4cc94dc79), [commit 4074d3c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4074d3c7e1a3b44c5c02235799d798f8b2613333), [commit 7903efb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7903efb7170ca9704e80ef9188bef37ecf55f2d6), [commit 512fccf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/512fccf8a503bd8617fe46cb62c77480b83fbaea), [commit c93c3d2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c93c3d2fa42bec64948441cb339d78e2044ff9a3), [commit 7bc73e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7bc73e7b61e60cbc0730a4f0e938c482c459e000), [commit d9fd674](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9fd674c8b26c376b37e02d974b92033acb99732), [commit e72171f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e72171f085e48ed9292809815bf70b6e685b73c6) (31 Jan 2023) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4f59836](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f598364519f5bb871caf12a482ed117a270588b), 15 Feb 2023)</sup>

> ### [`clone`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4074d3c7e1a3b44c5c02235799d798f8b2613333): set fetch.bundleURI if appropriate
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> Bundle providers may organize their bundle lists in a way that is intended to improve incremental fetches, not just initial clones.
> However, they do need to state that they have organized with that in mind, or else the client will not expect to save time by downloading bundles after the initial clone.
> This is done by specifying a bundle.heuristic value.
>
> There are two types of bundle lists: those at a static URI and those that are advertised from a Git remote over protocol v2.
>
> The new fetch.bundleURI config value applies for static bundle URIs that are not advertised over protocol v2.
> If the user specifies a static URI via '[`git clone --bundle-uri`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4074d3c7e1a3b44c5c02235799d798f8b2613333/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L326)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---bundle-urilturigt))</sup>, then Git can set this config as a reminder for future '[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4074d3c7e1a3b44c5c02235799d798f8b2613333/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> operations to check the bundle list before connecting to the remote(s).
>
> For lists provided over protocol v2, we will want to take a different approach and create a property of the remote itself by creating a `remote.<id>.*` type config key.
> That is not implemented in this change.
>
> Later changes will update '`git fetch`' to consume this option.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4074d3c7e1a3b44c5c02235799d798f8b2613333/Documentation/config/fetch.txt#L99-L106):

> ### `fetch.bundleURI`
>
> This value stores a URI for downloading Git object data from a bundle
> URI before performing an incremental fetch from the origin Git server.
>
> This is similar to how the `--bundle-uri` option behaves in
> [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).
> `git clone --bundle-uri` will set the
> `fetch.bundleURI` value if the supplied bundle URI contains a bundle
> list that is organized for incremental fetches.

---

"[`git fetch --all`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89833fc249189d5b91509b1b3f16b26aade9e7f7/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> does not have to download and handle the same bundleURI over and over, which has been corrected with Git 2.41 (Q2 2023).

See [commit 25bccb4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25bccb4b79dce1d5c259228ef3c91eadcd13d8ac) (31 Mar 2023) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 89833fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89833fc249189d5b91509b1b3f16b26aade9e7f7), 06 Apr 2023)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25bccb4b79dce1d5c259228ef3c91eadcd13d8ac): download bundles once, even with `--all`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> When `fetch.bundleURI` is set, '[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/25bccb4b79dce1d5c259228ef3c91eadcd13d8ac/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> downloads bundles from the given bundle URI before fetching from the specified remote.
> However, when using non-file remotes, '`git fetch --all`' will launch '`git fetch`' subprocesses which then read `fetch.bundleURI` and fetch the bundle list again.
> We do not expect the bundle list to have new information during these multiple runs, so avoid these extra calls by un-setting fetch.bundleURI in the subprocess arguments.
>
> Be careful to skip fetching bundles for the empty bundle string.
> Fetching bundles from the empty list presents some interesting test failures.