# How to get source code from GitHub data export?

Tags: github, export

I decided to backup all my github data and found this: https://help.github.com/en/github/understanding-how-github-uses-and-protects-your-data/requesting-an-archive-of-your-personal-accounts-data

I managed to get the `.tar.gz` file and it seems to contain all my repositories but there is no source code in there. Judging by the size, it looks like some kind of archive in `objects/pack/*.pack`

Is there any way to access original source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it looks like some kind of archive in objects/pack/*.pack

According to [Download a user migration archive](https://developer.github.com/v3/migrations/users/#download-a-user-migration-archive):

> The archive will also contain an attachments directory that includes all attachment files uploaded to GitHub.com and a **`repositories`** directory that contains the repository's Git data.

Those might be **[bare repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5540883/6309)** or [bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578292/6309).
Once uncompressed, try and `git clone` one of those folders (to a new empty folder)

The [OP johnymachine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2320749/johnymachine) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59835563/how-to-get-source-code-from-github-data-export/60519553?noredirect=1#comment107071803_60519553):

```
git clone .\repositories\username\repository.git\ .\repository\
```

Meaning `repository.git` is a bare repo (Git database only, no files checked out)

Comment: git clone .\repositories\username\repository.git\ .\repository\ works like a charm.

Comment: works most brilliantly, but I am only able to get master branch. How do I get all the branches?

Comment: @Mayank Do a `git branch -avv` in your repository: you should see all remote branches listed as `origin/xxx`. A `git switch xxx` would update your repository with that branch content.

Comment: @Mayank If not, that means GitHub policy when exporting data is to export only the default branch.

Comment: Much Appreciated @VonC! your earlier solution worked.