# Azure DevOps repo Backup Copy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

We have created repository on https://dev.azure.com/
It's working fine.
Now my manager wants a backup copy of this repository on a regular basis. 
I explained to manager that https://dev.azure.com/ is managed as SAAS by MS so repo is safe always.
But he wants a copy of own. It is what is it!!

I thought of few options:
a) Get latest on any developer machine and take backup into tape device
b) Use some infra of Azure DevOps to keep backup on  Azure Storage

How feasible is option b?

Is backup of Azure DevOps possible with all past check-in history?

Any backup service on Azure DevOps that I can link with Azure Storage?

Is incremental backup possible using some xyz service on Azure DevOps?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to back up. If it's the source code: it uses git, so you can clone the repo anywhere you want. If it's the Work Items (epics/features/stories/tasks), those are all exportable. Aside from that: this is more of a tooling documentation question, and not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How feasible is option b?

It's possible in Azure Devops Service. What you need is a [Yaml pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/pipelines-get-started?view=azure-devops#define-pipelines-using-yaml-syntax) which [triggers all branches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers).

You can use [command line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to backup the repo into `{RepoName}.git` folder, and then copy this folder into Azure Storage using [Azure File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops). Similar to this:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: 'git clone --mirror https://{Your PAT}@dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_git/{RepoName}'

  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/{RepoName}.git'
      includeRootFolder: true
      archiveType: 'zip'
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Backup.zip'
      replaceExistingArchive: true

  - task: AzureFileCopy@4
    displayName: 'AzureBlob File Copy'
    inputs:
      SourcePath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Backup.zip'
      azureSubscription: xxxx
      Destination: AzureBlob
      storage: xxxxxxxx
      ContainerName: arm
      BlobPrefix: test
```

**Details:**

1.CI Trigger with wildcard(*) can monitor all your branches. So if there's any update with your repo, the pipeline will be triggered to run.

2.The cmd task calls [git clone --mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578270/fully-backup-a-git-repo) to make the copy of your git repo. To copy Azure Git repo in cmd task with PAT, you can follow the format [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#use-your-personal-access-token):

`git clone https://{yourPAT}@dev.azure.com/yourOrgName/yourProjectName/_git/yourRepoName`

This command will create a `RepoName.git` folder which contains the copy of your repo in this path: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`. To [create PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page), you only need to create one with Code-read access scope:

[image]

3.The logic is: If there's any change to your source repo=>The pipeline will be triggered=>It make a latest copy in DefaultWorkingDirectory(CMD task)=>Archive this copy into a `Backup.zip` file([Archive file task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops)=>Azure File copy task will copy this `Backup.zip` to Azure storage blobs)

Comment: I tried using this same approach but it gives error on first step itself. I have a PAT with full access, and used as above, but it gives 400 error : "fatal: unable to access <Repo Name>". I also tried using Powershell after encoding PAT with base64, but still same issue. Any help on this please.