# Git push speed fluctuating and slow - how to speed up?

Tags: git, git-push

I'm pushing a repo that's about 100mb in size. Unfortunately I have to use WiFi on my PC upstairs, and my upload speed is around 10mbps, or 1.25MB/s. Slow, but manageable. Or, it would be if it was consistent.

However, when I `git push` over either HTTPS or SSH, it goes like this: https://del.dog/cecaghygru.txt

As you can see it ranges anywhere from 1.1MiB/s to 43KiB/s. In about 15 seconds it only got about 20 objects uploaded out of ~600k. I get that that's a large amount, and this is the first time pushing, so the whole repo is being pushed to Git, but why does the speed fluctuate so much? Is there anything I can do to improve the speed of git push?

(Also, I'm not sure why it says "Sending approximately 1.53 GiB ..." when the folder containing my repo is definitly not that size).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are pushing your Git repository to, you might consider [making a bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578292/6309), and copying that one file (bundle) to a workstation closer to your remote repo target.

You can also look at the content of your local repository [to identify large objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622179/how-to-find-identify-large-commits-in-git-history) and see if they could be removed.

Finally, make sure you are using the latest Git 2.28, as it includes many optimizations.

Comment: Yes, I am using Git 2.28. Unfortunately I can't remove anything from the repo. I tried making a bundle, however it still for some reason uses the network and displays essentially the same log as when using git push. Is it because of other remotes?

Comment: @NateDev The bundle is just an option to copy over the repository to the target, as one file, from which you can fetch.

Comment: Yeah, I mean when I'm creating the bundle is when it displays the same log - it's just supposed to create a file on my PC I can transfer and use on another PC (the one with better internet). Here's my command and the output (which is the same as git push) https://del.dog/ihemonullo.txt.
Thanks

Comment: I would create the bundle outside the repository: ../my bundle