# How to move local git repository to another machine and use it?

Tags: git, ssh

I sometimes use my local git repository to track changes I make before submitting it to our official project git repository.
I'm doing the same thing for a new project on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine now, but this time, because the working directory and my local repository is in the same hard disk (both in /dev/sdb1), if the hard disk fails, I won't be able to recover the data. This makes me feel uneasy, so I thought I should move the repository to another machine I own(It's Centos 6.9 machine) because I don't have another hard disk installed in the Ubuntu current machine.
So I tar'ed the ProjS.git directory (repository) from the Ubuntu machine, and ftp'd it to my CentOS machine and untar'ed it on /home2/repos.ProjS.git in the CentOS machine.  And in the ubuntu machine's ~/testgit directory, I tried

```
ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/testgit$ git clone ssh://ckim@129.254.xxx.yyy/home2/repos/ProjS.git/
Cloning into 'ProjS'...
ckim@129.254.xxx.yyy's password: 
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: ----
ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/testgit$ fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The CentOS mahcine has never been used as a git repository for external machines. (But it had served as git repository for internal users, actually the same user me).  In this case, what should I do? (maybe I should give access permission to myself.)

Comment: why wouldnt you make a branch(something like 'backup') with your code and then pull it from the new machine?

Comment: @berlin branch or not, the problem is pulling from another machine. The repos was pull only at the local machine. Now I want to put the repos in a remote machine and pull it from my current machine(ubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of tar'ing the repository, I would use the [`git bundle` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) (as I described in "[Fully backup a git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578292/6309)")

That will result in *one* file that you can copy over (`scp` for a copy over SSH), and clone.

```
 git clone myrepo.bundle
```

Once cloned, you can add the original repo SSH URL, but make sure to generate an SSH key, and register the public one to the original server.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P""
# copy ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub in 129.254.xxx.yyy:/home/ckim/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

That way, no password to ask.
Make sure the `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` in `/home/ckin` is silent (does not output strings)

Comment: Thank you. this works! (I just used the tar'ed repos so it wasn't crucial). Two important things were the ssh key thing(I expected something like this) and removing a print coming out from the .cshrc in CentOS account(maybe this was the direct problem, because .cshrc spat out ---- pattern.). Thank you very much!