# I suddenly get a Permission Denied (the contents of .git/objects files) error when trying to copy my repository via scp

Tags: git, ssh, scp, permission-denied

So I'm new to both git and ssh, so some basic terminology might be wrong in what I'm saying.

I'm trying to copy (with `scp`) my repository (I also backup this repo via github,so it has a `.git` folder) to a remote machine that I access via ssh.

It always worked before.

Then I added another branch from `master` and kept working on the code on that new branch.
I don't know of anything other I changed that could be significant here.

Anyways, now the old `scp -r` command to copy the repository to the remote machine uploads my normal files but it fails in "`.git/objects`":

```
scp: /scratch/petzi/remote/meins/.git/objects/43/50c1b2c7306710fad08153c12fd4a394aef0fc: 
     Permission denied
```

And the equivalent message for all kinds of files (maybe even all, I haven't checked) in "`objects`".

How can I get past those error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you `scp -r` the full repository each time? Git has been developed to synchronize the code between multiple machines, but you are using `scp` do to it (although you are using git).

If you want to keep code synchronized between two machines and you already have a git repository in github, then just use the github repository as a canonical repository to synchronice your machines.

**Asumming you already have a git repository in the remote machine**.
After you made changes in your local machine:

1. commit your code
2. push your code to github (something like `git push origin master`)
3. `ssh` to your machine
4. `cd` to the git repository path
5. get your code from github (something like `git pull origin master`)

Comment: Alright, thanks. Using git pull makes sense of course, so I do it like that now.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using scp, to copying every single files, [use `git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578292/6309), and scp only *one* file. Less errors.

```sh
cd /path/to/local/myrepo
git bundle create ../myrepo.bundle --all
scp ../myrepo.bundle remoteUser@remoteServer:~/myrepo.bundle
```

On the remote server:

```sh
cd /path/to/myrepo
git remote add bundle /home/remoteUser/myrepo.bundle
git fetch bundle
git switch master
git merge bundle/master
```

You can clone or fetch from a bundle, which (again) is *one* file representing your repository.