# Re-instating automatic deployments after git repo wiped out?

Tags: git, githooks, git-deploy

I have a question about how to start using automatic deployments after the git repo on our client's site has been wiped out.

*What happened to the repo?* The client wanted to use a feature on their hosting provider where they can make copy edits to a staging site and "push" it to the live site. After they pushed edits, the git repo disappeared.

*Automatic deployments*: We're using git hooks do deployments. Here's a good [how-to](https://anchor.host/automatic-git-deploy-with-kinsta-via-ssh/). Basically, you can make deployments locally using `git push <environment> <branch>`. When you run this command, git runs the following `post-receive` hook (site name removed for privacy):

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET="/www/[sitename]_571/public"
GIT_DIR="/www/[sitename]_571/private/[sitename].git"
BRANCH="master"

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
        # only checking out the master (or whatever branch you would like to deploy)
        if [[ $ref = refs/heads/$BRANCH ]];
        then
                echo "Ref $ref received. Deploying ${BRANCH} branch to production..."
                git --work-tree=$TARGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f
        else
                echo "Ref $ref received. Doing nothing: only the ${BRANCH} branch may be deployed on this server."
        fi
done
```

The structure of the remote server is:

/www/[sitename]_571/ -> private -> `[sitename].git` -> hooks
                                     -> public -> website files + `.git`

What's the least destructive way to get git back on the live site, so we can start making deployments again?

Thanks!

Comment: I noticed after posting this that the live server actually does have the git repo intact. My mistake was expecting `git log` to return anything, which is never will with the set up I have. Not sure if my question is still valuable - mods can delete if appropriate.

Comment: A *repository* is self-contained (in the `.git` directory) and consists of commits and ancillary data. A *checked-out working tree* is the result of extracting one commit; it does not contain the information needed to restore a repository. So you can't go from commit to repository unless you still have the repository, or a clone or backup of it.

Answer (score 0):

> When you run this command, git runs the following post-receive hook

That means you need to restore a bare repository copy "`myrepo.git`" on the server, in which you will restore the `myrepo.git/hooks/post-receive` hook.

Then you can push again, and the hook will, from the bare repo, checkout your site with `git --work-tree=$TARGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f`

You can:

- [make a bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578292/6309) of your current repository,
- copy that bundle (one file) to the server, and
- `git clone --bare mybundle myrepo.git` on the server.