# Why "--bare" flag is being frequently used when deploy the applications by Git to VPS?

Tags: linux, git, version-control, vps

AFAIK besides the version management functionality Git is being frequently used for the deploying of the applications to VPS. Please note that in this question we are discussing the deploying without third-party services like GitHub, Docker Hub, AWS and like - only Git and VPS with initially bare Linux.

When I collected the information myself, for example, inputted "create Git remote" search request, the GitHub was frequently getting in the way among searching results. However, it was some related articles like [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-git-server-on-a-vps). I have noticed that when creating the Git repository at VPS, the `--bare` flag of Git CLI frequently being used.

### Requirements

In my case, the source code and output code are *completely* split, and there is *no* need to submit the *source* code to VPS. So, I have prepared the subrepositories for the output code (even one for staging and one for the production):

[image]

For this question, it does not matter where is the remote for the main module of Git repository (this remote even could not be!). What actually matters is there are two remotes must be prepared in VPS: one for staging and one for production.

[image]

### Report about own efforts

1. Connected to VPS and created the directories at `var/www` of VPS:

   ```bash
   sudo mkdir example.com
   sudo mkdir staging.example.com
   ```
2. Initialize the repository in each directory

   ```bash
   cd example.com
   git init --bare
   cd staging.example.com
   git init --bare
   ```

   Looks like

   ```bash
   git init --bare example.com.git
   git init --bare staging.example.com.git
   ```

   is another option, but what I don't understand what we'll receive if will have `.git` suffix.
3. Grant the access rights to above repositories

   This step is frequently missing in articles and manuals =)

   ```bash
   sudo chown -R me example.com
   sudo chown -R me staging.example.com
   ```
4. Set the remote locally and push the submodule

   In my case, the connection with below URIs is fine.

   ```
   me@160.XXX.XX.97:/var/www/example.com/
   me@160.XXX.XX.97:/var/www/staging.example.com/
   ```

### Question

If we'll navigate to `var/www/example.com/`, its content will be:

```
.  ..  branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs
```

And what I need to with it now?
How I can launch the application?

The expected contents must be like:

[image]

Then, the application could be launched by Docker CLI.

### The problem of the restarting application

Designing the solutions it is required to this about how to restart application when pushing the new version of the application. Basically, once new commit(s) pushed, it is required to restart the Docker by CLI. However, looks like we need to respect something else working with Git repository initialized with `--bare` flag.

### Update about  [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/846621)

In comments, I has been told that:

- I am using bare repos wrong
- I am generally using the Git for targets for which Git has not been designed
- It is better to upload the Zip file (by FTP?) or use rsync for this targets.

In fact, I mainly agree.

> ...using bare repos wrong

Well, that is right because currently I don't understand the concept of bare repos.

> ... generally using the Git for targets for which Git has not been designed

Well, Git has not been designed for deploying.
But I have see repeatedly in tutorials how the whole repository including source code is being uploaded by Git to VPS,
and then built there from source.
I'll never do such thing because I think source code must not be in VPS.

> ... it is better to upload the Zip-file (FTP?) or use rsync for this targets.

It is pretty important part, so I'll consider each tool separately.

#### FTP/Zip

- **Deleting of obsolete files**: Not available (it is required to delete all files of previous version of build, then upload new ones)
- **Automation**: Maybe possible. The uploading could be provided by **gulp-ftp**, but I am not sure is there the simple way to automatically delete all files of previous build because the deleting command must be run on VPS, not on local machine
- **Rollback to previous versions**: Not available

The uploading of Zip file is the standard method, but I want the approach with better optimization and automation.
Ideally, only button click in IDE and everything has been deployed.
It is possible to write some gulp task and run it by IDE.

#### Rsync

- **Deleting of obsolete files**: Yes (with `--delete` option)
- **Automation**: Yes (for example, with **gulp-rsync**)
- **Rollback (to previous versions)**: Not available

I have tried Rsync before tried to use the Git for deploying.
Being shortly, although it is available on Windows, the [SSH functionality does not work correctly](https://superuser.com/q/1766875/1689508).
The usage of MacOS or Linux local environment is not the solution - is is running away from the problem.
The development environment must be cross-platform, and that's it.

If you are recommending me to use the Rsync instead of Git for deploying, it is fine, but first [this problem](https://superuser.com/q/1830328/1689508) must be solved.

#### Git

Why I have tried to use the Git for the deploying are the problems with Rsync and:

- **Deleting of obsolete files**: Yes
- **Automation**: Yes (just push the changes and deploying done)
- **Rollback (to previous versions)**: Yes

Comment: You seem to be confusing two use cases. A bare repo makes sense for a central repo like what you would have on Github, but self-hosted. For the actual deployment of course you want the checked-out files  (a working copy), not the bare repo which only allows you to access the files (and branches, versions, etc) through the various Git APIs.

Comment: Rather than an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), this feels like an X/Y/Z/Banana problem - you've made so many weird decisions, you need to [nuke the whole thing from orbit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nuke_it_from_orbit). Storing compiled code in git is generally a bad idea; using sub-modules to track releases is a weird idea; using git to then deploy this compiled code is just over-engineering. If you really want to keep it simple, build the code, and upload it as a zip file or using rsync. Keep a backup if you want, but not in git.

Comment: @IMSoP Thank you for opinion. Maybe you right, but there is not everything fine with alternatives. Before trying to use Git for deplying, I tried the Rsync. Although it is available for Windows, it [does not work as on Linux](https://superuser.com/q/1766875/1689508).  I still don't know how to make the rsync use the correct SSH keys without explicit specifying of them on Windows. That is why I am trying the various alternatives including Git.

Comment: Sorry if my comment came across as harsh, but what I'm suggesting is that you step back and think about what problem you're actually trying to solve, before building something over-complicated, and using git for something it is definitely not designed for. A much more common solution is to zip up the release, and upload it with something simple like `scp`; then unzip on the remote host and move into place - possibly using symlinks to instantly switch between two live paths, so you never have half of one release and half of another. What do you need that that doesn't do but you think git would?

Comment: @IMSoP I have updated my question. Maybe it will answer on your one.

Comment: The answer to "Why "--bare" flag is being frequently used when deploy the applications by Git to VPS?" is "It is not, so the 'why' is impossible to answer"

Answer (score 2):

The instructions you have found are not for *deploying* anything to a remote server, they are for *hosting your own git server* - taking the role of GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, etc

When you "clone" a repository in git, you are normally creating two things:

- A copy of the *database* containing the entire git history, generally in a directory called `.git`
- A *working copy* of the tree of files as at a particular revision, for you to work on, test, etc

You may be familiar with the difference between `git fetch` and `git pull`: when you "fetch" revisions from a remote server, you are *only* updating your local database; whereas `git pull` does this fetch followed by a *merge* (or, optionally, a rebase) of a particular remote branch into your working copy.

When you "push" changes, you are actually doing the same thing as "fetch", but in reverse: you're updating *the remote copy's database*. No files are actually going to be checked out on the remote server.

For running a central server, like GitHub, all you are going to do with the copy is let people push changes to the database, so *you don't need a working copy at all*. That's what `git clone --bare` is for: it creates a copy of the *database* of the repository, without checking out any separate working copy. It leaves you with only what would normally be in the `.git` directory.

So, not only is `--bare` not what you're looking for, your assessment of git for deployment is wrong:

> Automation: Yes (just push the changes and deploying done)

Running `git push` won't force an update to the *checked out code* on another server; and as far as I know, there is no way to do so. When people "use git for deployment", they are talking about having a full working copy, and some trigger or timer which runs something like `git pull --ff-only` *on the remote server*.

This makes some sense for applications which don't need any "build" step - the code is already in git, and pushed to some central server for collaborating, so pulling it down onto the server is easier than setting up a proper deployment pipeline.

That doesn't seem to be your case. You have an explicit build step, which puts its results into a different folder. Your requirement is to copy that folder onto the remote server, *completely independent* of what you're normally using git for.

A more common, and less complicated, way to achieve your goals would be:

1. Run your build process, targeting a local folder
2. Put that folder into an archive (`.zip` or `.tar.gz` file), named with an incrementing release number, or a timestamp
3. Upload the archive to the remote server, using something simple like `scp`
4. Run remote commands to unzip / untar the file, retaining the unique name (release number / timestamp)
5. Run remote command to point a symlink to the new version; your web server config points at this symlink, giving you an atomic release, and easy rollback

```
/srv
   /my-site
       /live [symlink] -> /srv/my-site/releases/4
       /releases
           /1
               /index.html [etc]
           /2
               /index.html [etc]
           /3
               /index.html [etc]
           /4
               /index.html [etc]
```

Answer (score 1):

> If we'll navigate to var/www/example.com/, its content will be:
>
> ```
> .  ..  branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs
> ```
>
> And what I need to with it now? How I can launch the application?

While Git is indeed not done to deploy, it can be used to automate a repository content checkout.

Since a [bare repository](https://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/) has no working tree, you can push to it without overriding any repository content (since the repository content is *not* checked out: that is the all point of a *bare* repository).

You can add to that bare repository a [post-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks), which can be configured to checkout what is pushed to any local folder of your choice (as [i this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69128665/6309)).

It is interesting in your case if the repository content is what you want to deploy.

Most of the time, what you intend to deploy is *not* in a source control referential, but in a binary referential ([Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/products/sonatype-nexus-repository), [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/blog/what-is-artifactory-jfrog/)), and the target machine gets the artifacts from those referentials, not Git.