# Distributing GH actions over private GH repos / docker repos

Tags: github-actions

The GH actions docs says:

The actions you use in your workflow can be defined in:

- A public repository
- The same repository where your workflow file references the action
- A published Docker container image on Docker Hub

I work for a customer with GH private repositories only, so distributing over public repos is not an option. I wonder what could be an alternative?

As I see it's also possible to distribute actions using docker containers, but again they should pulled from public Docker Hub, or maybe there is alternative to use private docker repositories?

Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure I understood your question: Your customer has a github action located in a private repository that need to be shared on other private repositories? Or do you want to use GH actions in your customer private repositories?

Answer (score 0):

In both case (private repository or docker image), you would need to package them as an archive, and transfer them through a secure channel (or USB key), in order to import said repository/image in the client environment.

- for repository, you would [use a `git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578292/6309) to generate one file representing the full repository and its history.
- for docker image, you would [`docker save`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) it.