# How can I add my github repo to local gerrit server?

Tags: git, github, gerrit

I'd like to use gerrit for the code review before merging into my Github repo.

First, I installed gerrit server to the local machine following [this](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.4.2/dev-readme.html). Followings are what I entered when initializing gerrit server:

```
$ java -jar gerrit-war/target/gerrit-2.6-SNAPSHOT.war init -d ../test_site

*** Gerrit Code Review 2.4.2-689-g10b8774
*** 

Create '/Users/pj/git/test_site' [Y/n]? 

*** Git Repositories
*** 

Location of Git repositories   [git]: 

*** SQL Database
*** 

Database server type           [H2/?]: ?
       Supported options are:
         h2
         postgresql
         mysql
         jdbc
Database server type           [H2/?]: 

*** User Authentication
*** 

Authentication method          [OPENID/?]: ?
       Supported options are:
         openid
         openid_sso
         http
         http_ldap
         client_ssl_cert_ldap
         ldap
         ldap_bind
         custom_extension
         development_become_any_account
Authentication method          [OPENID/?]: development_become_any_account

*** Email Delivery
*** 

SMTP server hostname           [localhost]: 
SMTP server port               [(default)]: 
SMTP encryption                [NONE/?]: 
SMTP username                  : PJ Kim
PJ Kim's password              : 
              confirm password : 

*** Container Process
*** 

Run as                         [pj]: 
Java runtime                   [/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home/jre]: 
Copy gerrit.war to /Users/pj/git/gerrit/../test_site/bin/gerrit.war [Y/n]? 
Copying gerrit.war to /Users/pj/git/gerrit/../test_site/bin/gerrit.war

*** SSH Daemon
*** 

Listen on address              [*]: 
Listen on port                 [29418]: 

Gerrit Code Review is not shipped with Bouncy Castle Crypto v144
  If available, Gerrit can take advantage of features
  in the library, but will also function without it.
Download and install it now [Y/n]? 
Downloading http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk16-144.jar ... OK
Checksum bcprov-jdk16-144.jar OK
Generating SSH host key ... rsa... dsa... done

*** HTTP Daemon
*** 

Behind reverse proxy           [y/N]? 
Use SSL (https://)             [y/N]? 
Listen on address              [*]: 
Listen on port                 [8080]: 

*** Plugins
*** 

No plugins found.
Initialized /Users/pj/git/test_site
Executing /Users/pj/git/gerrit/../test_site/bin/gerrit.sh start
Starting Gerrit Code Review: OK
Waiting for server to start ... OK
Opening browser ...
$
```

The browser opened, and I created an account, logged in. Then I clicked 'Projects > Create New Project', filled in 'Project Name' only, and clicked 'Create Project' button.

I can see the project name created on 'Projects > List', but have no idea how to connect my github repo (for example `git@github.com:philipjkim/vimrc.git`) to gerrit project. Thanks for any advices/corrections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to push an existing repository (from github or elsewhere) into Gerrit, we just had a discussion on that at [Getting local gerrit and repository working (including branches) based on a github project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269963/getting-local-gerrit-and-repository-working-including-branches-based-on-a-gith).  Good luck!