# what is the difference between git clone --mirror and git clone --bare?

Tags: git, codemirror

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between git clone --mirror and git clone --bare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959924/whats-the-difference-between-git-clone-mirror-and-git-clone-bare)

man git-clone indicates that:

> implies --bare

so what is the difference between them?

is --bare more powerful than --mirror option?

[What's the difference between git clone --mirror and git clone --bare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959924/whats-the-difference-between-git-clone-mirror-and-git-clone-bare) said  --bare option has no expectation of fetching again, then can i fetch new commits to that bare repo? is that allowed to fetch new commits when --bare option is used while cloning a project.

Comment: Voting to close as exact duplicate. You should also read the rest of the documentation for `--mirror`, which explains the difference. If you have a question about what that paragraph *means* (I'm not sure I entirely understand it myself), you might update your question to clarify what you're asking about -- assuming the other question doesn't already explain it for you.

Comment: @R0MANARMY i have searched, not find it the first time, after i find it, i cannot delete this question

Comment: @hugemeow if you put in the title `what is the difference between git clone --mirror and git clone --bare`, that's the first suggested question.  You'll have to excuse my skepticism about not finding it.