# What is the difference between git clone and git clone --mirror?

Tags: git, github

Can someone please give me the details on

**git clone** or **git clone --mirror**

Thanks. I am trying to make backups of my github repos and I am using it in a script.

I don't know what the difference is and I need someone to help me with the backups.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between git clone --mirror and git clone --bare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959924/whats-the-difference-between-git-clone-mirror-and-git-clone-bare)

Answer (score 0):

> --mirror
>
> Set up a mirror of the source repository. This implies --bare.
>   Compared to --bare, --mirror not only maps local branches of the
>   source to local branches of the target, it maps all refs (including
>   remote-tracking branches, notes etc.) and sets up a refspec
>   configuration such that all these refs are overwritten by a git remote
>   update in the target repository.

You'll get a bare repository, with all branches. This is what you want for a backup.

Comment: Did you try it and take a look, or take a peek in the man pages, or Google "git bare repository" or such?