# Difference in 'git clone --bare' between git 1.7 and 1.8: copying remotes

Tags: git, git-clone, git-bare

Suppose I've got a simple git repository with a remote named origin:

```
$ cd test
$ git init
$ git remote add origin git@example.com:project.git
```

Then if I make a bare clone of it in git 1.7.0.4, it doesn't copy any information about remotes:

```
$ git --version
1.7.0.4
$ git clone --bare test cloned && cd cloned && git remote
$ # says nothing
```

With git 1.8.4, however, origin is successfully copied:

```
$ git --version
1.8.4
$ git clone --bare test cloned && cd cloned && git remote
origin
```

With corresponding entry in cloned/config:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@example.com:project.git
```

This just makes a quite popular [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3960060/817441) not correct, because `git clone --bare && git remote add` no longer works (git refuses to add a remote that has already been added).

My question is: am I missing something in git help that says remotes copying is an expected behaviour since some version of git? And when exactly did this behaviour changed? I couldn't find any information in release notes neither.

Comment: IIRC in earlier git version you needed to say `git --bare clone`, but it might not be about 1.7.x vs 1.8.x, and I might remember it incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, probably. But I've started using git when it was at version 1.7, and `git clone --bare` is a correct command.