# Mirroring a git non-bare repository

Tags: git, repository, workflow

I need to have a "robot user" that interacts with a git bare remote repository through some scripts. This bare repo is called central repo.

A this time, this robot user have its own local repository which is not a bare repository (he has to checkout branches, merge branches, ...). But every night, when he wake up to work, he needs to have locally a perfect mirror of the central repo (every branch except master could have evolve, some new branches could have been created, ...).

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not as straightforward as the previous answer suggests, because `git pull` only incorporates changes into the current branch.

The first thing your bot needs to do is `git fetch` - and while it is true that a `git pull` would (by default) cause this to happen, I recommend doing the `fetch` directly to avoid potentially-confusing side effects.

When you do a `fetch`, what you get depends on the `remote.central.fetch` configuration option (for a remote named `central` as you indicated).  The default setting after a `clone` (assuming you didn't specify something like `mirror`, `single-branch`, or `depth` without `no-single-branch` to the `clone` command...) would fetch the histories of all branches, and would update remote branch refs (e.g. `refs/origin/central/master` to indicate the condition of the `master` branch on `central`).

If you stick with that, then your local refs are still not in sync with the remote.  Whether that's a problem depends on what your bot is doing.  There are a lot of permutations here... Might your bot have local changes before the `fetch`, and if so what would you want to do with them? Will your bot make changes after the `fetch`, and ultimately will it then push those changes?  Plus any number of "if you want the history to come out looking like X, do Y" considerations.

I will say that if your intent is to move all the local branches to reflect the corresponding branch on `central`, there are two basic approaches:

1) Leave the refspec in the default setting, then iterate over branches updating the local ref to match the remote.  This gives you the opportunity to deal with any local changes (by either merging or rebasing them into the branch history), but it takes a fair amount of scripting.

2) Change the refspec to look like it would on a mirror clone. (I get the sense this is what you were getting at, with how you worded the question.)  This is perhaps risky because local changes could just get clobbered, and you still would have to identify any branches that had been deleted on `central`.  The setup here would be something like

```
git config remote.central.fetch +refs/*:refs/*
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward (if by perfect mirror you mean [all branches, but not other refs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959924/whats-the-difference-between-git-clone-mirror-and-git-clone-bare)).

Cloning the bare repo without `--bare` results in a normal repo. After doing this once, your robot simply has to

```
git pull
```

when he gets to work.