# How to make git cloned mirrored repo not `mirror`?

Tags: git

I like a way to copy repo via `clone --mirror` as it copies all branches. However, it results in config that still AFAIK not ready for pull/push etc.:

```
[core]
    bare = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/*:refs/*
    mirror = true
```

Using `--mirror` posted e.g. here [Move git repo with git clone --mirror and git push --mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387671/move-git-repo-with-git-clone-mirror-and-git-push-mirror), I've tried to add

```
git remote set-url origin my-url (two tries: where target was - current, and new empty folder)
git push --mirror
```

But still same `config`, however in answers I have not found mentioning of similar issue.

Maybe it is so easy to fix it was omitted? How to make target to track repo the source is tracking? Just remove `mirror = true` and edit `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` by hand? TIA

Comment: Sandboxes are cheap, just make another one. Mirrors are useful for some things, but it's best to make a regular clone for development work.

Comment: But, my real question is, *why* do you want to convert your mirror to a regular clone? Is there something important in this particular mirror you don't want to lose?

Comment: @joanis, I want to clone all local branches of remote. Maybe now there is a command in git to do that? IIRC people suggested scripts to loop all branches. Other solution was to use `clone --mirror`. Now I realized there is something important to be done after cloning.

Comment: When I do `git clone <repo url>`, I get all branches, so I'm not sure yet what you're trying to solve that a regular clone does not do.

Comment: By the way, short answer to the question as asked: while I'm sure it's possible to convert a mirror clone to a regular clone, it would be a fair amount of finicky work that would require a very good understanding of how Git stores information. That's a job for an advanced user, so it's best you find a different solution for what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: @joanis. `man git clone` "and creates and
       checks out an initial branch that is forked from the cloned repository’s currently active
       branch.". So it creates only one branch.

Comment: @joanis, writing scripts to loop branches IMO is also advanced. I still wonder why not have option to create all branches by `git clone` but only one?

Comment: Oh, well, yes, only one branch is *checked out*, but all branches are fetched. Run `git branch -a` to see them all. Or `git log --all` to see their graphs. Then you can check out any branch you want locally from there.

Comment: Please spell out more precisely what you are actually trying to accomplish. It's not clear yet. What's your end goal?

Comment: @joanis. I'd like those newly checked out branches to be properly set to track remote origin. I doubt `checkout` does that.

Comment: @joanis, "all branches are fetched". fetched but not pulled. I recall clone of linux kernel is times more on disk when ` --mirror ` added.

Comment: @joanis, some people like to be able to work off-line sometimes.

Comment: So you mean you want a local `my_branch` set up from each `origin/my_branch` on the remote? Again, why? From a clone, you will already have all those `origin/my_branch` fetched on your local computer. Note: "pull" is just fetch + merge. It's the fetch part of that operation that downloads the branch to your computer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250361/discussion-between-joanis-and-martian2020).

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer here to summarize the long chat:

In order to have all the branches downloaded locally for doing development (possibly) offline from a repo, you should use a regular clone rather than a mirror clone. It downloads all the remote-tracking branches from the remote, and Git can then create local branches from them whenever you need them.

A mirror clone is useful for other situations, like mirroring a whole repo (as the name says), uploading the mirror elsewhere, possibly backups, but not for use as a sandbox.

Converting between types would not be easy, it's best to make the right kind of clone in the first place.

Something I learned from the discussion: a mirror clone from GitHub (and possibly other Git servers with PRs or MRs) includes the refs to the PR head and merge commits, in `packed_refs`, while a regular clone does not include them.

Comment: Thanks again for the discussion. Later I recalled that w/out `--mirror` in cloned linux kernel repo one can see only current kerkel, , with `--mirror` repo gives also previous versions (accessed via tags). I have a guess now old commits were merged and deleted, only recent left, that is why previous kernel versions are not available w/out  `--mirror` . Does above make sense?

Comment: @Martian2020 Not to me, no. Regular and mirror clones both include all the tags.

Answer (score 1):

That answer is based on comment by @torek in [Why line with "fetch" in git config effects how `git branch --set-upstream-to` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74785335/why-line-with-fetch-in-git-config-effects-how-git-branch-set-upstream-to-w)

1. change the fetch URL in `.git/config` from `fetch = +refs/*:refs/*` to `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`
2. git config --bool core.bare=false (or edit `.git/config`)
3. create `.git` folder and move everything there (I usually do clone so that this step in not needed, via `git clone --mirror "$1" "./.git"`)
4. remove `mirror=true` line from `.git/config` (the line is initially in `config`, but it was not in @tokek comment and I don't know if it effects `git` work)