# Azure DevOps Git - Copy A Repository From One Project To Another Project

Tags: git, github, azure-repos

I am working on copying a repository from a source project to destination project in Azure DevOps Services. We will not use the Source repository any more. Going forward all development changes will be done in destination repository .The Git Version I am using is

```
C:\>git --version
git version 2.39.2.windows.1
```

I use the following commands to copy the repository.

```
git init --bare
git config remote.origin.url https://<AzureDevOps_OrgName>@dev.azure.com/<AzureDevOps_OrgName>/<Source_Project>/_git/<Source_Git_Repo_Name>
git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
git config remote.origin.mirror true

git remote update

git push --mirror https://<PAT>@dev.azure.com/<AzureDevOps_OrgName>/<Destination_Project>/_git/<Destination_Git_Repo_Name>
```

Please let me know if this is the correct approach. If there are any other suggestions , that will be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried it? Was there a problem?

Comment: @Schwern - I tried this and did not see any issues, but since I am very new to Git, wanted to check for a feedback

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the specifics of the AzureDevOps URL.

If your intention is to have an exact copy of the old repository, including any remote tracking branches, that looks correct. That's called a "mirror".

It can be written more succinctly as...

```
git clone --mirror https://<AzureDevOps_OrgName>@dev.azure.com/<AzureDevOps_OrgName>/<Source_Project>/_git/<Source_Git_Repo_Name>

cd <Source_Git_Repo_Name>

git push --mirror https://<PAT>@dev.azure.com/<AzureDevOps_OrgName>/<Destination_Project>/_git/<Destination_Git_Repo_Name>
```

The first [`git clone --mirror`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---mirror) does all the configuration and updating for you.

See:

- [Mirroring a repository in another location](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository). (Doesn't matter that it's a Github doc)
- [What's the difference between git clone --mirror and git clone --bare?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959924/whats-the-difference-between-git-clone-mirror-and-git-clone-bare).

Comment: When I try the above approach .. ! [remote rejected] refs/pull/3423/merge -> refs/pull/3432/merge )The current action can only be performed by the system.) . where as when I use the approach which I mentioned in the question, it works fine. Any thoughts why it would do that

Comment: @Joe_12345 Which command is giving you the error?

Comment: I got the above error when executing the git push -mirror command.

Comment: @Joe_12345 Was the destination repository empty? There's [a few SO questions about this same error](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+%22The+current+action+can+only+be+performed+by+the+system%22+site:stackoverflow.com&sca_esv=568238426&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi69662psaBAxUhNzQIHcWFBroQrQIoA3oECB8QBA&biw=1082&bih=815&dpr=2).