# Git Alias - Multiple Commands and Parameters

Tags: git, sh, alias, git-alias

I am trying to create an alias that uses both multiple Git commands and positional parameters. There are Stackoverflow pages for each, and it would appear painfully obvious to do both, but I am having trouble.

As an example, I want to switch to branch foo and perform a status.  So in my `.gitconfig`, I have:

```
  [alias] 
     chs = !sh -c 'git checkout $0 && git status'
```

which doesn't work.  Whereas something like this will work.

```
chs = !sh -c 'git checkout $0'

echoes = !sh -c 'echo hi && echo bye'
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: My alias:  git config --global alias.go '!git commit -a && git pull --rebase && git push && git status'.
Note: Use simple quotes.

Comment: also, you always have the option to make an alias in your "bash" config.

Answer (score 203):

This will work (tested with zsh and bash):

```
[alias] chs = !git checkout $1 && git status
```

Comment: No it won't. Git will transform `git chs foo` into `git checkout && git status foo`

Comment: When I try that, I get pathspec error ('$1' did not match any file(s) known to git)

Comment: I tested it, it works perfectly... perhaps it depends on your shell? (I use zsh)

Comment: Interesting, git actually does fill in the positional variables now in shell aliases. But it's still broken, because it also tacks them on as arguments. An alias of `echo $1 && echo done`, when invoked with the argument 'foo', will output both "foo" and "done foo".

Comment: Wow... Unfortunately, this was all a version problem.  I was using Git 1.7.3, and neither of these methods worked.  I updated to 1.7.6 and voila, everything worked.  Thanks guys!

Comment: Works for me also, git version 1.7.4.4

Comment: What is the preceding exclamation point for on the first invocation of `git`?

Comment: @ElijahLynn: In a git alias, a leading `!` means pass the whole thing to the shell. Otherwise, it assumes you're trying to run another git command and passes it as arguments to the `git` binary.

Comment: Comment also added as an answer, please shout if I should remove one post or the other.

In a windows environmend (cmd line, or msysgit bash) you can append `&& :` to your alias, and that will consume the additional insertion of the parameter (turns it into a location tag, which isn't printed.)

Don't know whether this, or some equivalent will work in other environments.

Comment: @Brondahl Clever. I'd recommend `;:` instead of `&& :` though. And that works just fine on unix as well.

Answer (score 136):

This targets Windows batch / msysgit bash; might not work on other environments.

As Olivier Verdier and Lily Ballard have said

`[alias] chs = !git checkout $1 && git status`

almost works, but gives a spurious extra insertion of the argument ...

`git chs demo -> git checkout demo && git status demo`

But if you add `&& :` to the end of your alias, then the spurious argument is consumed into a location tag.

So

```
[alias] chs = !git checkout $1 && git status && :
```

gives the correct output ...
`git chs demo -> git checkout demo && git status`

Comment: The `&& :` is gold and makes this solution work for commands where the extra argument would be problematic.

Comment: @Clay (or anyone else) - Could someone explain to the BASH-challenged what `&& :` does?

Comment: @JustinMorgan && means if the previous command turns 0 (success), then run the command after &&. ':', the colon, is a shell builtin command, which does nothing beyond expanding arguments and performing redirections and return the status 0. Here're some usages: 1. `a=123;$a` errors, but `a=123; : $a` does not. 2. `: > hello.txt` empties hello.txt. 3. `if [ "$a" = "hello" ];then : ;fi` runs okay but errors without ':'. It's like `pass` in python. 4. `: this is a comment`, the colon followed by space works as `#` in a comment line.

Comment: this is such a hack... git should accept multiple command mode

Comment: @kchoi So true :) And yet it appears to be a well-valued hack by the community :D

Comment: if you use quotes, ending an alias with a comment is better: `[alias] chs = !"git checkout $1 && git status #"` - it will turn extra arguments into comments that won't do a thing

Comment: Thanks @ElpieKay for the explanation. My local git alias for one proejct was `co = !git checkout public/compiled && git checkout $1` and when I'd do `git co master` I'd get the message `error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.`. I didn't think this answer would be useful for me because the first thing it mentions is Windows and I'm on Linux. But you explained why.

Comment: Does git v2.2x still have these issues?

Comment: @DevinGRhode No idea. Why don't you test it and tell us?

Answer (score 95):

You can define a shell function.

```
[alias] chs = "!f(){ git checkout \"$1\" && git status; };f"
```

Comment: I saw this on another stackoverflow page, but my cygwin terminal says that the function is not recognized when I try to run it.

Comment: @Stella: I left a closing quote in there that's not useful this config file syntax. Make sure you didn't have it.

Comment: Wow... Unfortunately, this was all a version problem.  I was using Git 1.7.3, and neither of these methods worked.  I updated to 1.7.6 and voila, everything worked.  Thanks guys!

Comment: @Stella: That sounds very strange. AFAIK the git alias stuff hasn't changed in quite a long time. I can't think of any reason whatsoever why upgrading from 1.7.3 to 1.7.6 would cause a simple shell alias to start working. But I guess I shouldn't question something that worked ;)

Comment: if using Windows I think you have to surround the shell function definition with double-quotes `"`

Comment: Olivier's answer didn't work for me using parameters (OSX). This worked perfectly.

Comment: Huh, I wonder why it differs. I'll go ahead and update my answer to include the quotes. And it looks like `git config` does quote the value by default when it writes it in the first place.

Comment: Great,thanks, other solutions don't work, but this does:
[alias]
        reset-hard = "!f(){ git reset --hard origin/master && git clean -fd; };f"

Comment: Man, I just lost 20 minutes to solving this. The point is to use SINGLE ' and not double " quotes to make it work.

Comment: The command I was trying to run gave `cannot update paths and switch to branch at the same time` when I used Oliver or Brondal's answers, but this worked fine.

Answer (score 39):

I was able to create multi-line and quite complex git aliases. They work fine on Windows but I assume they'd work elsewhere too, for example:

```
safereset = "!f() { \
                trap 'echo ERROR: Operation failed; return' ERR; \
                echo Making sure there are no changes...; \
                last_status=$(git status --porcelain);\
                if [[ $last_status != \"\" ]]; then\
                    echo There are dirty files:;\
                    echo \"$last_status\";\
                    echo;\
                    echo -n \"Enter Y if you would like to DISCARD these changes or W to commit them as WIP: \";\
                    read dirty_operation;\
                    if [ \"$dirty_operation\" == \"Y\" ]; then \
                        echo Resetting...;\
                        git reset --hard;\
                    elif [ \"$dirty_operation\" == \"W\" ]; then\
                        echo Comitting WIP...;\
                        git commit -a --message='WIP' > /dev/null && echo WIP Comitted;\
                    else\
                        echo Operation cancelled;\
                        exit 1;\
                    fi;\
                fi;\
            }; \
            f"
```

I wrote a post and have a few more examples [here](https://medium.com/@vitalyb/creating-powerful-git-aliases-3dfc0efc9a31).

Comment: one imrovement to this would be to add `!f() { : reset` to get completions from reset command https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L25

Comment: Great job! What licence is that article published under? Would you mind if I translate parts of it for StackOverflow in Russian?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Sorry about late reply. Thank you and of course, go ahead :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, did you translate it eventually?

Comment: For something like this, it may be easier to maintain as a shell script. Then, your alias would be something like `safereset = !bash ~/safereset.sh` where `bash` is whatever shell you want, or just `safereset = !~/safereset.sh` if the script is executable and you want to run it in your user's login shell. Using an absolute path is probably a good idea, though `~` appears to be handled just fine.

Answer (score 28):

```
[alias]
chs = !git branch && git status
```

Comment: What is the `!` for?

Comment: I couldn't find doc for the `!` but as far as I can see git by default will assume that the alias is a git command so `t = status` will work. However if you try `t = git status` it won't work (will say "git" command not found). So that where the `!` comes in, it tells it to run the command as if it was a shell, and normally you need this when you have multiple git commands per alias, so you can have `t = !git status && git log` for example and it will work.

Comment: Here's a StackOverflow question that deals with exclamation points (!) in Git aliases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083933/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-mean-in-git-config-alias.

Comment: If the alias expansion is **prefixed with an exclamation point**, it will be treated as a **shell command**. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Answer (score 13):

```
[alias]
      chs = !git checkout && git status
      ac = !git add . && git commit -m
```

what is ! ?

> If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be treated as a shell command. [What does the exclamation mark mean in git config alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21083933/5661396)

To call alias from .gitconfig file

```
git chs
git ac "write_your_commit_message"
```

alias is more useful for add and commit in git you can do more fast
[image: Gif show more datails]

Answer (score 7):

Try this one:

```
[alias]
    chs = "!sh -c 'git checkout \"$0\" && git status'"
```

Call it like this: `git chs master`

Answer (score 7):

It's possible to have multiline git alias by appending `\` at the end of each line.

```
[alias] 
   chs = "!git checkout $1 \ 
          ; git status     \
         "
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually had no problem using `"!git fetch --prune --all; git pull --rebase upstream master; git push origin master"` for my alias.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that the positional parameters seem to be getting sent to the shell command twice (as of git 1.9.2).  To see what I mean, try this:

```
[alias]
  test = !git echo $*
```

Then, do `git test this is my testing string`.  You should observe the following output (last two lines edited here for clarity):

```
03:41:24 (release) ~/Projects/iOS$ git test this is my testing string
this is my testing string this is my testing string
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          #1                         #2
```

One way to work around this would be to

```
[alias]
  chs = !git checkout $1 && git status && git echo x >/dev/null
```

This will consume the extra positional parameter as it gets applied to that last echo command and have no effect on the results.

Comment: Your example will expand to:
    git echo this is my testing string this is my testing string

Adding a # to the end will fix it (don't forget the double quotes around the command alias).

Comment: in .gitconfig: a0 = "!echo $*" and a1 = "!echo $* #" . To test them: git a0 hallo daar ; git a1 hallo daar

Comment: @imme What does the # at the end do? It worked for me but I'd like to understand it.

Comment: See this "demo" https://stackoverflow.com/a/63890372/165330 (it seems that git adds the arguments after replacing the alias with the defined alias, using $* in the alias already puts the arguments in there, so the rest should be ignored, which happens with the # at the end, making the rest of the command a comment.

Answer (score 3):

An example for people who want to try out what different aliases do.

Putting this in the alias-section of GIT's configuration-file (e.g. `~/.gitconfig`) :

```
[alias]
    a0 = "!echo $*"
    a1 = "!echo $* #"
    a2 = "!f () { echo \"$*\"; }; f "
    a3 = "!f () { echo \"$*\"; }; f #"
    a4 = "!f () { echo \"$*\"; }; f \"$*\" #"
    a5 = "!f () { echo \"$*\"; }; f \"$@\" #"
    a6 = "!f () { echo \"$*\"; }; f \"$1\" #"
```

And then executing this command:

```sh
cat ~/.gitconfig | grep --extended-regexp -- '(a[0-9])|(alias)' ; \
echo "" ; \
export CMD ; \
for I in {0..6} ; \
do \
    CMD="a""${I}" ; \
    echo -n "Executing alias.${CMD} = " ; \
    git config --global alias."${CMD}" ; \
    git $CMD 'hoi daar' en nu ; \
    git $CMD hoi daar en nu ; \
    echo "" ; \
done ; \
unset CMD ;
```

Should give this as output:

```
[alias]
    a0 = "!echo $*"
    a1 = "!echo $* #"
    a2 = "!f () { echo \"$*\"; }; f "
    a3 = "!f () { echo \"$*\"; }; f #"
    a4 = "!f () { echo \"$*\"; }; f \"$*\" #"
    a5 = "!f () { echo \"$*\"; }; f \"$@\" #"
    a6 = "!f () { echo \"$*\"; }; f \"$1\" #"

Executing alias.a0 = !echo $*
hoi daar en nu hoi daar en nu
hoi daar en nu hoi daar en nu

Executing alias.a1 = !echo $* #
hoi daar en nu
hoi daar en nu

Executing alias.a2 = !f () { echo "$*"; }; f 
hoi daar en nu
hoi daar en nu

Executing alias.a3 = !f () { echo "$*"; }; f #



Executing alias.a4 = !f () { echo "$*"; }; f "$*" #
hoi daar en nu
hoi daar en nu

Executing alias.a5 = !f () { echo "$*"; }; f "$@" #
hoi daar en nu
hoi daar en nu

Executing alias.a6 = !f () { echo "$*"; }; f "$1" #
hoi daar
hoi
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but no one has provided what I think is the simplest solution.  This works in my *nix-based CLI, your mileage may vary.

```
[alias]
    chs = "!git checkout $1; git status"
```

A simple semi-colon (;) is all you need to run multiple git commands.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Lily Ballard have a good answer with a shell function, it looks better when we pipe all the alias arguments:

```
[alias] chs = "!f(){ git checkout \"${@:1}\" && git status; };f"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmu = "!f() { git add . && git commit -m $1 && git push -u origin $2; }; f"
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?