# How can I revert a single staged deleted file from git branch?

Tags: git

I am trying to recover staged deleted files from my local branch. I tried git checkout file name, but it did not work. I don't want to use reset hard as it will reset all my required changes that I made to the other files. So is there a way to restore the deleted files only?

Comment: Try `git reset -- <file>` followed by `git checkout -- <file>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unstage a deleted file in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591407/unstage-a-deleted-file-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. `git reset <filename>` should reset a single file only.

You can also do a `git show HEAD:<filename>` and save the output back to *filename*, then just `git add` it back in.

Answer (score 0):

Let's restate the question first.

Given this output from `git status`:

```
$ git status
On branch SOMEBRANCH
Your branch is up-to-date with ...

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    SOMEFILE
```

You now want to get file `SOMEFILE` back into both the work-tree and the index, so that the `git status` output will *not* say `deleted:    SOMEFILE`.

#### Method 1: follow the advice `git status` gives

If you follow the advice that `git status` itself prints:

```
$ git reset HEAD SOMEFILE
```

the status will change to:

```
$ git status
On branch SOMEBRANCH
Your branch is up-to-date with ...

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    SOMEFILE
```

Now you have to take the advice shown again in `git status`:

```
$ git checkout -- SOMEFILE
```

#### Method 2 (short-cut)

The text just above Method 1 is the key to the short-cut.  We want to copy the file `SOMEFILE` from the `HEAD` commit into the index, then copy the file `SOMEFILE` from the index into the work-tree.  There is a command that does this: it's `git checkout`:

```
$ git checkout HEAD -- SOMEFILE
```

The trick is that when you say `git checkout -- SOMEFILE`, you are telling Git to copy the file *only* from the index to the work-tree.

This is why it takes two steps to do it the way `git status` suggests: the first step, `git reset HEAD SOMEFILE`, copies the file from the `HEAD` commit to the index.  The second step, `git checkout -- SOMEFILE`, copies the file from the index to the work-tree.  Using the `git checkout HEAD -- SOMEFILE` syntax we make Git copy from `HEAD` to index first, then from index to work-tree, all with one command.

(But the advice that `git status` gives works too.)