# Git restore command not found

Tags: git, gitlab, git-bash

I am new to git and software development field. I was referring to below link to learn few git commands.

https://medium.com/@iamsohail/git-commands-to-master-810cad71e22d

As and when I try to use the "restore" command , I get the error message "Restore command not found".

I am unable to find the solution to this. Any help appreciated.

I am using git version below 2.23.

Comment: Well [`git restore` does exist](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore). Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*git restore* command is only available from git version 2.23+.
I think you are using a git version below than that.

Comment: Any proposed workaround you want to add in this answer?

Comment: If you are stuck using an older version that does not have `git restore` the alternative is:
`git checkout -- <file>` (as described by the prompt after typing `git status`)

Answer (score -1):

in GIT versions prior to 2.23+ you can use the command:

```
$ git log --oneline
$ git reset --hard c42dd8d2
```

*The first command (git log --oneline) shows the revisions with their code, and then we pass the code to the second command (git reset --hard).*

This will rewind your HEAD branch to the specified version. All commits that came after this version are effectively undone; your project is exactly as it was at that point in time.

Comment: Just a friendly note, but this is not the same as restore. This will revert your entire working tree. `git restore` will act only on the files specified in the argument. Be careful with reset until you know what it does.

Comment: @rocksNwaves if you're right.

He could also use:

`git checkout -- file`

or

`git checkout -- .`