# Unable to unstage a deleted file with git

Tags: git, delete-file, git-stage

After I checked out a branch and did a "git pull" on it, git thinks that I have deleted a file:

```
> git status
On branch feature-support
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature-support'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    mvnw
```

However, that is not true, as the `mvnw` file is still in the directory. I have tried the following commands from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591407/unstage-a-deleted-file-in-git) and other answers and I am not able to unstage this deleted file, which is preventing me from unstashing some files:

```
git restore --staged mvnw
git reset -- mvnw
git checkout -- mvnw
git reset HEAD mvnw
git reset HEAD .
git reset HEAD
git restore --staged -- mvnw
git reset mvnw
git checkout mvnw
git checkout .
git reset --hard
git clean -fd
git clean -f
```

How can I unstage that deleted file?

EDIT: Running the `git restore --staged .` command resolved the issue for the `mvnw` file, however, a new deleted file showed up in `Changes to be committed` and I can't get it to go away:

```
deleted: our-project/src/test/resources/etc/ABCD-EFGH.
```

Comment: `git restore --staged mvnw` will have unstaged the deletion. `git restore mvnw` will restore the file

Comment: No matter what I do, it is still listed in `Changed to be committed: deleted: mvnw`. How can I remove 'mvnw` from `Changes to be committed`?

Comment: It appears you tried multiple things that should have unstaged the file. I wonder if there is some funky permissions things occurring where the index was written by a different user and you cannot modify it. Like another program running as admin/root, etc. Or maybe another program just has the index locked.

Comment: What OS are you on ?

Comment: @LeGEC Windows 10, running Git 2.34.1.windows.1

Comment: could it be a case sensitivity issue ? check what files are versioned in git: `git ls-files HEAD | grep -i msnw` and what files you have on disk: `ls | grep -i msnw`

Comment: @LeGEC Nothing is returned when I do `git ls-files HEAD`

Comment: @pacoverflow: my bad, I meant `git ls-tree HEAD | grep -i mvnw`, and obviously, you should grep for the name of your file (`mvnw`, not the mistyped name `msnw` I wrote before). Does `ls | grep -i mvnw` show a line where `mvnw` would be spelled with a different casing ? (`Mvnw` or `MVNW` or ...)

Comment: @LeGEC I tried `git restore --staged .` which got rid of the `deleted: mvnw`, but oddly replaced it with a different file `deleted: our-project/src/test/resources/etc/ABCD-EFGH.` which is still on the disk. The `git ls-tree HEAD` command outputs info about the files/dirs in the current directory. Should I do something different for the `ABCD-EFGH` file?

Comment: I think this will work: `git checkout HEAD -- mvnw`.. given everything you have tried, I wouldn't bet. Just in case, this should also work: `git show HEAD:mvnw > mvnw` even if indirectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `mvnw` file, I resolved the issue with the `git restore --staged .` command.

For the `our-project/src/test/resources/etc/ABCD-EFGH.` file, I resolved the issue with the `git config core.protectNTFS false` command. Viewing the `our-project/src/test/resources/etc/` directory on GitHub, I can see 3 files:

```
ABCD-EFGH
ABCD-EFGH.
ABCD-EFGH.pdf
```

It appears Windows cannot handle a file named `ABCD-EFGH.` (with a dot at the end), and the `git config core.protectNTFS false` command resolves that. I still see `deleted: our-project/src/test/resources/etc/ABCD-EFGH.` in the `Changes not staged for commit` section, but it is not preventing any git operations like it did when it was listed under the `Changes to be committed` section.