# Git alias with variables not working as expected: pathspec did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, alias, git-bash

I have created an alias for catching up my tracking branches as needed. Here's the current line from the `[alias]` section of my .gitconfig:

```
catchup = !CURRENTBRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) && echo Currently on $CURRENTBRANCH - switching to $1 && git checkout $1 && git merge origin/$1 && echo Going back to $CURRENTBRANCH && git checkout "$CURRENTBRANCH"
```

I use it as follows (for example):

```
git catchup new_design
```

This code results in (for example):

```
Currently on integration
Switched to branch 'new_design'
Your branch is behind 'origin/new_design' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
Updating c82f7db..51eea8a
Fast-forward
 themes/theme1/css/styles.less | 17 +++++++++++++++++
 themes/theme1/js/app.js       |  6 +++---
 2 files changed, 20 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
Going back to integration
error: pathspec 'new_design' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I have tried the last command in the alias both with and without the double-quotes, with the same result.

Anyone know how to resolve that error at the end?

For those who might suggest using `git pull`, it doesn't resolve my problem, and  would require entering my password. This alias is to be used if I have recently used `git fetch`, and have no need to go back to the remote repo.

I am running git bash on Windows 7, fyi.

Comment: Even though it should already be the case, try: 1/ adding a `git fetch` as the first command, 2/ `git checkout -t $1 origin/$1` when firs t switching.

Comment: Are you saying this is the cause of the error? The idea is to only use this on pre-existing tracking branches. I tried it anyway - it gave `fatal: Missing branch name; try -b`, and then if I use `git checkout -t origin/$1` (which looks more correct) I get `fatal: a branch named 'new_design' already exists`

Comment: Can you add a `git branch -a` before the last `git checkout`? (to check on which branch git think you are after the merge)

Comment: Could it be that git automatically appends the parameter (here `new_design` in `git catchup new_design`) to the end of the command string when executing it? This would mean that the last command is actually `git checkout integration new_design`, and this gives this error message.

Comment: @VonC: git symbolic-ref --short HEAD would be a more concise output, but yes, I have tried this and confirmed that I am on the expected branch at that point.

Comment: @Phillipp Wendler: that sounds like it might be a possibility. How would I check this?

Comment: @PhilippWendler that is exactly what was happening - as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534184/git-alias-multiple-commands-and-parameters#comment9128399_7534289

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a shell function for the alias:

```
[alias]

catchup = "!f() { CURRENTBRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) && .... ;}; f"
```

There the handling of `$n` works as expected.

---

The [OP mwotton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283991/mwotton) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776015/git-alias-with-variables-not-working-as-expected-pathspec-did-not-match-any-fil#comment17294150_12780101) that the following works:

```
catchup = "!_(){ CURRENTBRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) ; echo \"Currently on \"$CURRENTBRANCH\" - switching to \"$@ ; git checkout $@ ; git merge origin/$@ ; echo \"Going back to \"$CURRENTBRANCH ; git checkout $CURRENTBRANCH; }; _"
```

In multi-line, for more visibility:

```
catchup = "!_(){ 
  CURRENTBRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) ; 
  echo \"Currently on \"$CURRENTBRANCH\" - switching to \"$@ ; 
  git checkout $@ ; 
  git merge origin/$@ ; 
  echo \"Going back to \"$CURRENTBRANCH ; 
  git checkout $CURRENTBRANCH; }; _"
```

Comment: This is going to require more skills in shell scripting for bash than I currently have. A quick try gives: `f: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token \`{CURRENTBRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)' f: -c: line 0: \`f(){CURRENT
BRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) ; echo Currently on $CURRENTBRANCH - switching to $1 ; git checkout $1 ; git merge origin/$1 ; echo Going back to $CURRENTBRANCH ; git checkout $CURRENTBRANCH)}; f "$@"'`

Comment: Nevermind, I got my skills up to scratch. I ended up with this: `catchup = "!_(){ CURRENTBRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) ; echo \"Currently on \"$CURRENTBRANCH\" - switching to \"$@ ; git checkout $@ ; git merge origin/$@ ; echo \"Going back to \"$CURRENTBRANCH ; git checkout $CURRENTBRANCH; }; _"`

Comment: @mwotton good feedback, and +1 to Stefan. I took the liberty to include your conclusion in Stefan's answer for more visibility.

Comment: Where can I get some documentation on things like '$@' and '@-1' - no idea what those are?

Comment: @MarkGibaud I used http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ to learn bash scripting. Before I embarked upon this endeavour, I had no real bash scripting experience. This guide got me through, but you will need to be patient.

Answer (score 1):

Late for the party.. The reason it failed is that git runs the command as

```
git catchup new_design
# turns
CURRENTBRANCH= ... && git checkout "$CURRENTBRANCH\" new_design
```

That is, it appends "new_design" to the command. A proof of this is simple to demonstrate:

```
# [alias]
#   proof = !echo fixed text

> git proof tryme
# prints "fixed text tryme", not "fixed text"
```

So, an alternate option to [stefan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12780101/3645375) is to use the comment trick

```
# [alias]
#   proof = "!echo fixed text #"

> git proof tryme
# prints "fixed text", since command it ranned was
# echo fixed text #tryme

catchup = "!CURRENTBRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) && echo Currently on $CURRENTBRANCH - switching to $1 && git checkout $1 && git merge origin/$1 && echo Going back to $CURRENTBRANCH && git checkout \"$CURRENTBRANCH\" #"

# multiline version:
catchup = "! \
  CURRENTBRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) && \
  echo Currently on $CURRENTBRANCH - switching to $1 && \
  git checkout $1 && \
  git merge origin/$1 && \
  echo Going back to $CURRENTBRANCH && \
  git checkout \"$CURRENTBRANCH\" \
#"
```

Notes:

- `"!..."` and `!"..."` are equivalent
- watch out for "\ " endings (with spaces after), it won't work!
- this trick works even with use of "all parameters" (`$*`), since it prevents at all the append