# Git alias appending parameters to end

Tags: git

I'm using Git Bash v1.8.1, with a few aliases (for testing):

```
[alias]
    ekko = !echo $1 && echo $1
    ekko2 = !sh -c 'echo $1 && echo $1'
```

But when I run them, I see:

```
> git ekko master
master
master master
```

And:

```
> git ekko2 master
(blank line) 
(blank line)
```

My intended behavior is:

```
> git ekko master
master
master
```

I'm fairly new to aliases - I'm looking for a way to ensure that my arguments are consumed entirely, and not appended to the end of the alias. Some sleuthing indicates this behavior changed somewhere around Git v1.7.x, and I haven't yet determined exactly how to accomplish this:

[Git Alias - Multiple Commands and Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534184/git-alias-multiple-commands-and-parameters#comment9128399_7534289)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git alias with positional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `ekko2` alias is really close... What you really want is this:

```
[alias]
    ekko2 = !sh -c 'echo $1 && echo $1' -
```

Git aliases that execute shell commands do substitute the `$n` variables, but they also append any arguments you pass them to the end of the command. So in your first example `git ekko master` is equivalent to `echo master && echo master master`, which explains its output.

Your second example is closer, but you're passing "master" to the `sh` command, which is just ignoring the extra argument. By adding `-` to the end of the alias, you're telling `sh` that the arguments that follow are intended for the script `sh` is executing, and not for `sh` itself.

Comment: Just for the record, another relatively common way to achieve the same result is to use a function: `ekko2 = "!f() {echo $1 && echo $1}; f"`. It's potentially slightly more efficient, as it avoids forking a second shell, I think...

Comment: For me, `ekko2 = "!echo $1; echo $2 #"` worked. The `#` suppresses the rest of the line.

Comment: thanks @donquixote that '#' is making it all! don't know why I hustle so much to find this solution, it's much simpler than the !f() { ... }; f

Answer (score 5):

`ekko2` is missing a single dash at the end:

```
[alias]
    ekko2 = !sh -c 'echo $1 && echo $1' -
```

See the [Git Wiki on Advanced aliases with arguments](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Advanced_aliases_with_arguments):

```
[alias]
    example = !sh -c 'ls $2 $1' -
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add a Bash noop command ":" at the end:

```
git config --global alias.hello-world '!echo "$1"; :'
```

Prints:

```
$ git hello-world hello world
hello world
```

Answer (score 3):

On a Windows 10 machine using the standard command line the character `#` needs to be appended to the end of the alias and the whole alias wrapped in `"` characters. Eg.

```
[alias]
    ekko = "!echo $1 && echo $1 #"
```

Comment: You saved my day!!! All other answers I saw dealt with linux or included some complicated unmaintainable stuff, this one is simple and reliable.