# Syntax for Git aliases with multiple commands

Tags: git

I want to create a Git alias to perform multiple commands, but I cant find documentation on how this is done.

1. What is the syntax for Git aliases with multiple commands?
2. Where is this documented?

***From 'man git-config'***

> ```
>    alias.*
> ```
>
> Command aliases for the git(1) command wrapper - e.g. after defining "alias.last = cat-file commit HEAD", the invocation "git
>   last" is equivalent to "git cat-file commit HEAD". To avoid confusion
>   and
>              troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing Git commands are ignored. Arguments are split by spaces, the usual shell
>   quoting and escaping is supported. quote pair and a backslash can be
>   used
>              to quote them.
>
> If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be treated as a shell command. For example, defining
>   "alias.new = !gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD", the invocation "git new" is
>              equivalent to running the shell command "gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD". Note that shell commands will be executed from the
>   top-level directory of a repository, which may not necessarily be the
>   current
>              directory.  GIT_PREFIX is set as returned by running git rev-parse --show-prefix from the original current directory. See
>   git-rev-parse(1).

Comment: Are you referring to aliasing in general, or is there a special `git alias` set of commands I haven't heard of?

Comment: Does it have to be an alias, or could you just write a small shell script that executes the commands you want?

Comment: @BlackVegetable you can specify aliases in .gitconfig, which might have the same syntax as aliasing in general.

Comment: @R0MANARMY I would like it to be a git alias. Mostly I want to know how the 'advanced' syntax for git alias works. I now believe the examples I have seen are shell scripts imbedded in git aliases.

Comment: See [git alias with positional parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3321492/1256452)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
$ git config alias.q '!echo a; echo b'

$ git q
```

Output:

```
a
b
```

I think this is (rudimentarily) documented in `man git-config` under `alias.*`

Note that git commands should include git, unlike in normal aliases. It is caused by fact that it is treated as a shell command, not as a git command (see manpage quoted in the question). For example to chain

```
git init
```

and

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "empty initial commit"
```

it is necessary to create

```
"!git init; git commit --allow-empty -m \"empty initial commit\""
```

alias.

Comment: This did not work for me on Windows; I had to use `&&` instead of `;`.

Comment: @TrueWill probably depends on the shell. [CMD.EXE uses `&` to separate commands](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html): _`If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line is processed as an immediate command in the new shell. Multiple commands separated by the command separator '&' or '&&' are accepted if surrounded by quotes.`_

Answer (score 26):

Say the commands are `echo a` and `echo b` (not `a` and `b`), to add multiple commands for an alias `q`:

From the command line:
`git config alias.q '!echo a; echo b'`

Directly in the configuration file:

```
[alias]
    q = "!echo a; echo b"
```

For more complex things, define a shell function and call it:
`'!f() { echo a ; echo b ; }; f'`

For passing parameters to the commands see:
[Git alias with positional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters-git-foo-aaa-bbb-ccc-foo-aaa-bar-bbb)
[Git Alias - Multiple Commands and Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534184/git-alias-multiple-commands-and-parameters)

Based in [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely)'s comment

Comment: Thank you, `'!f() { echo a ; echo b ; }; f'` was the answer I was looking for. I wanted to iterate over the arguments provided to the alias, `'!f() { for arg in $@; do echo $arg; done; }; f'`

Answer (score 2):

Addendum Answer: Often I need more complex commands that decide what to do through positional parameters and branch on the parameters or loop through parameters or input files.

Such commands are too complex for single liners and they are hard to read and edit on one line. But I found a real simple method to do very complex commands from files:

Assume you have a file called `alias/cmd` in your repository:

```
!function f {
    if [ -z "$1" ]
    then echo "Please give me some argument!" 1>&2
        exit -1
    fi
    echo "Hello $1"
}; f
```

then you can simply say

```
git config alias.cmd "`cat alias/cmd`"
```

to define the alias `cmd` from the file and

```
git config --get alias.cmd > alias/cmd
```

to write the defined alias to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to find a nice example for myself too. After some research, here's what I came up with:

```
git config --global alias.purge '!f() { if [ $(git ls-remote --heads origin $1 | wc -l) -eq 1 ]; then git branch -d $1 && git push origin --delete $1; else echo "remote branch not found"; fi } ; f'
```

Let's break that down from left to right, shall we?

**git config --global alias.** 
we know by now. It's the code we need in order to create an alias. Often referred to as [alias] on this site

**purge** 
is the shorthand name I decided to give to my alias

**'f() {** 
we start to write our function

**if [** 
the start of our if-statement, closing it later on with **]**

**git ls-remote --heads origin $1** 
checks if there is a remote branch with the name we supplied. Return value would be nothing if there's no branch, otherwise, it'll return the reference tag. By enclosing it in **$(   )** we make sure it's known to Bash as a command

**| wc -1** 
added as a suffix, converts the return value to 0 if there's no remote branch, 1 if there is

**-eq 1** 
turns the whole enclosed command into a boolean, read as (returnValue == 1)

> NOTE: because the commands are written on one line, instead of \n behind each, we need to type **;** after each command

**then** 
is used to announce what our function should do if the boolean returns true

**git branch -d $1** 
will delete the local branch of the parameter we entered

**&&**
this logical operator will ensure both commands are carried out

**git push origin –delete $1** 
will delete the remote branch of the parameter we entered

**else** 
does what the second half of an if-else should do

**echo "remote branch not found"** 
is a String I want to return in case there's no remote branch

**fi** 
announces the end of our if-else statement

**} ; f'** 
closes our function

[image: 'complex' git alias for my branch named "security"]