# Configure Alias on Git

Tags: git, git-config, git-alias

I want create more than one command in one line. Example:

```
git fetch && git pull
```

Is possible?

**This is my .gitconfig:**

```
[alias]
  rb = rebase
  s = status
  f = fetch
  p = pull
  fp = (git fetch && git pull ???)
```

Comment: Related [Syntax for Git aliases with multiple commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860696/syntax-for-git-aliases-with-multiple-commands)

Answer (score 1):

Just prepend an exclamation mark (!):

```
[alias]
  fp =!git fetch && git pull
```