# git shortcut for rebase and merge

Tags: git

I have the following branches where `A` is the current active branch:

```
*A  C
 | / 
 B
```

Often, I want to rebase `C` onto `A` and then merge `C` into `A`. So far I'm doing it with single commands:

```
git checkout C
git rebase A
git checkout A
git merge C

# and optional to clean up no longer needed branches
git branch -d C
git push origin :C
```

What would be a simple way to do this in one command? Is there a "git-way" or do I have to rely on a shell script?

Comment: I guess you have to use shell script only somewhat like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860696/syntax-for-git-aliases-with-multiple-commands or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534184/git-alias-multiple-commands-and-parameters but if the rebase causes any conflicts to occur then you might have an issue in merging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For routines like these I usually setup aliases:

```
git config --global alias.rebmerge '!git checkout C && git rebase A && ...'
```

or if you want to accept parameters:

```
git config --global alias.rebmerge '!f() { git rebase checkout $1 && git rebase $2 && ... }; f'
```

and then just call

```
git rebmerge A B C
```

Comment: Could you explain the `'!f() { ... }` a little bit more?

Comment: I know some people who use `hub` to have similar shortcuts, but I've never tried https://github.com/github/hub

Comment: @gusto `'!f() { ... }` here, '!' means shell script, `!f(){..}` is a function that takes `A`, `B` & `C` as parameter accessing by `$1`, `$2` & `$3`