# git alias: multiple commands, variadic parameters

Tags: git, git-alias

I often find myself typing this:

```
git push remote1 branch1 branch2 tag1 tag2 tag3..
git push remote2 branch1 branch2 tag1 tag2 tag3..
```

I would prefer an alias where I can type this instead:

```
git pushall branch1 branch2 tag1 tag2 tag3 ..
```

*Note: I am aware I could create a new remote "all" with multiple urls. Let's not discuss this here, but focus on the alias instead!*

I am ok to hardcode the remote names, because I have a number of projects with the same multiple remote names (usually "drupal" and "github").

### Progress so far

I already figured out a non-variadic version:

```
[alias]
pushall = "!git push github $1; git push drupal $1; #"
```

Two tricks here were

- using double quotes to prevent ';' from having a special meaning in `.ini` files
- `#` to ignore the rest of the line.

But this only pushes one branch (or tag) at a time. So I would have to type this:

```
git pushall branch1
git pushall branch2
git pushall tag1
git pushall tag2
git pushall tag3
...
```

I would prefer an alias where I can type this:

```
git pushall branch1 branch2 tag1 tag2 tag3 ..
```

### Why not a new remote "all" with multiple push urls?

As said, let's focus on the aliases, so that readers find what they are looking for.

Anyway, here is why I am not creating a remote "all":

- I would have to do this once per project, and could not do it globally. In my case, hardcoding the remote names in a global alias is actually fine!
- Afaik, I would pollute my history with refs like "all/branch1" instead of or in addition to "remote1/branch1" and "remote2/branch1".

The correct place to discuss this would be here, [pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations)

### See also

The following are related, but they do not address variadic parameters:

- [Git Alias - Multiple Commands and Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534184/git-alias-multiple-commands-and-parameters)
- [Syntax for Git aliases with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860696/syntax-for-git-aliases-with-multiple-commands)
- [Git alias with positional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters)

The following might be helpful, but it addresses pure shell script, not specifically git aliases:

- [How to iterate over arguments in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-bash-script)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters

Comment: @torek This link falls into the same category as the ones I already mentioned. I added it in the "See also" list for completeness.

Comment: The relevant piece of information I learn from the multiple answers is that `$@` means variadic arguments in shell script, and this also works for git aliases. I was not aware of this. Now I don't know which of those answers I should accept.. I will see.

Comment: The overall trick is to define your alias as a shell function, which then takes as its parameters, all the arguments passed to the alias. Then you get to use shell script, which is a real (nominally Turing-complete) language. In some special cases you don't need to resort to the full-power mode (axiac's answer) but I usually go straight to functions anyway, they're not that complex.

Answer (score 2):

This really is answered by the other questions which you linked to, but for clarity:

```
[alias]
    pushall = "!git push github \"$@\"; git push drupal \"$@\"; :"
```

Or setting from the command line:

```
git config --global alias.pushall '!git push github "$@"; git push drupal "$@"; :'
```

Comment: I did not see the `"$@"` mentioned in the other answers. Or at least not explicitly. I was not aware of this construct. For the record, I just found that this will also insert options like `-l` or `--version` (for `ls`). But the `--help` option is passed to the git command instead, it appears.

Comment: In a little test run this worked without the double quotes around `$@`. What could possibly go wrong if I omit those?

Comment: In this case, probably not much because you cannot have branch names with spaces or other characters that might cause changes to the parameter list during word splitting.

Answer (score 2):

The idiom to package an arbitrary script into a git alias is to put it inside a shell function:

```
pushall = "! f() { git push github \"$@\"; git push drupal \"$@\"; }; f"
```

I want to point out that the correct use of `$@` is to place it inside double-quotes: `"$@"`.

Answer (score 1):

By extending your initial attempt:

```
[alias]
pushall = "!git push github $@; git push drupal"
```

This way, `git pushall branch1 branch2 branch3` expands to:

```
git push github branch1 branch2 branch3; git push drupal branch1 branch2 branch3
#                  |               |                        |               |
#                  +-------+-------+                        +-------+-------+
# these arguments were     |                                        |
# expanded from $@ --------+                                        |
#                                                                   |
#                  these are the arguments of the original command -+
```

[`$@`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters) expands to all command line arguments.
There is no need for `#` at the end of line; the fragment `git pushall` is replaced by the value of the alias, the rest of the argument

If you have a bigger list of remote repositories you can write it this way:

```
[alias]
pushall = "!for repo in github drupal bitbucket; do git push $repo $@; done #"
#                         |               |
#                         +-------+-------+
# put all your repos here         |
# separated by spaces ------------+
```

This time the `#` sign is required. It turns the original arguments into a comment; otherwise the command has syntax errors and it doesn't run.

If you want to push to all the remotes of the repository then you can write a smarter alias:

```
pushall = "! for repo in $(git remote); do git push $repo $@; done #"
```

It runs `git remote` to find all the remotes and uses [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution) to replace `$(...)` with the output of the `git remote` command before continuing.

You can define it as a global alias using:

```
$ git config alias.pusha '! for repo in $(git remote); do git push $repo $@; done #'
```

If you have some repos where you don't want to push to all remotes, you can define it as a local alias and customize the list of remotes in each repo using thi command while you are in the repository:

```
$ git config --local alias.pusha '! for repo in github drupal; do git push $repo $@; done #'
```

Comment: I suppose omitting the `$@; #` at the end saves a few characters. But it also makes the entire thing less "symmetric". So maybe I prefer the slightly longer version.

Comment: I prefer the `for` version; it is more versatile. You can squeeze more commands (terminated by `;`) between `do` and `done`. For example, after `push` you can invoke a program (like `notify-send` on Ubuntu) that displays a desktop notification.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, the following "cheat" does work. It is not really a complete answer but it might be good enough for many.

```
[alias]
pushall = "!git push github $1 $2 $3 $4 $5; git push drupal $1 $2 $3 $4 $5; :"
```

Yes this is not truly variadic, because it is limited to 5 parameters (or whichever number you choose when creating the alias). Also it cannot pass options like `--key=value`. But as said it might be just good enough for you.

In my specific use case, most of the time I just push one branch and one release tag, so two parameters (`$1 $2`) would be enough.

Note that `:` at the end seems to have the same effect as `#`. I learned this somewhere else here on stackoverflow.

I will not "accept" this answer, because I want to leave the opportunity for someone to come up with something better.