# Git alias with multiple commands AND flags cannot work

Tags: git, terminal, sh

This has intrigued me this morning when I attempted to set a git alias by using

```
git config --global alias.ac '!sh -c "git add . && git commit -m $0"'
```

But it failed to work after `git ac "Finish static pages"` due to the error

```
fatal: Option -m cannot be combined with -c/-C/-F/--fixup.
```

It still gives me a headache after searching around. Why can't I combine -m option with `sh -c` and how should I do correctly to make this work? Much appreciated!

**Edit**
If I use

```
git config --global alias.ac '!sh -c "git add . && git commit -m $1"'
```

instead of `$0` in the end, it will say

```
sh: git add -A ; git commit --message Finish static pages: No such file or directory
fatal: While expanding alias 'ac': 'sh -i "git add -A ; git commit --message $1"': No such file or directory
```

I think I am looking for a way to accept an string instead of single word argument, maybe?

Comment: I am pretty sure cause i reproduce the same issue everytime, now i try to use other flags, but certainly these others are even more wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$1` instead of `$0`

```
git config --global alias.ac '!sh -c "git add . && git commit -m \"$1\""'
```

`$0` would repeat the entire command in your commit message. Meaning, [it isn't one of the positional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163260/6309).
And you can try adding double quotes for the message: `\"$1\"`

---

Other options exist for that kind of alias: see "[Git Alias - Multiple Commands and Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7534184/6309)".
For example

```
git config --global alias.ac '!f(){ git add . && git commit -m "$1"; };f'
```

Comment: It will invoke another error message, please see my new edit :-) Thank you

Comment: I think it fails to accept the following string "Finish static pages" is also a problem, maybe?

Comment: This is what we are talking about ;) Thank you