# Autohotkey not able to run command line in git command prompt

Tags: git, command-line, command-prompt, autohotkey, smartgit

So I'm trying to use Autohotkey to run a basic line script:

```
F19::
Send git checkout master; git pull; git merge nick; git push; git checkout nick; git merge master;
return
```

This works in any program but command prompt. I am using a mac keyboard on a windows machine, but have no issues with the F keys. I have this routed to F19. When I hit the key in git's command prompt within SmartGit, I get nothing. I've also tried rerouting the shortcut key to another bind, again with no result.

I am wondering if there is something in my command script that I am calling improperly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you considered just making an [alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534184/git-alias-multiple-commands-and-parameters)?

Comment: @R0MANARMY I've looked into it, but it seems I would have to make an alias for each git. I was hoping to run a single line. It seems that SourceTree's command line works with the short key, but command prompt and SmartGit's command prompt will not. While I would like to use Source Tree, a member in my team prefers I use SmartGit to keep consistent with the team.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "each git".  It should just live in your global `.gitconfig` and be available from every shell.

Comment: @R0MANARMY I mean by each git command "git checkout, git pull" etc... stringing them together in one line.

Comment: You do realize that `;` equals the `//`in other languages, right? If so, feel free to ignore my concern.

Comment: @Blauhirn No I did not. I am very new within PHP, and js and not familiar with anything outside CSS, HTML.

Comment: I don't understand any of your question, but then, use `; in your send command

Comment: As you are using SmartGit -- did you consider to define an external tool in the Preferences which invokes your commands (or a script containing your commands)?

Comment: @mstrap No, not at all. My knowledge of SmartGit is very limited, and I received training as far as, adding a repository, initial commit, adding a remote connection to the repo, and fetching/pulling/pushing/merging. Perhaps I should look at SmartGit's wiki for additional information instead of wasting your all's time. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

I would think a bash alias would work better in this situation.

`alias dostuff="git checkout master && git pull && git merge nick && git push && git checkout nick && git merge master"`

EDIT:

You could also make this more flexible by letting it take parameters ie. your branch name by using a function.

```
dostuff() {
  git checkout master && git pull && git merge $1 && git push && git checkout $1 && git merge master
}
```

Calling it with `dostuff nick`

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I'm doing it wrong. I tried running the following       git config --global alias.checkin "git checkout master && git pull && git merge nick && git push && git checkout nick && git merge master"   in the command prompt of git

Comment: What did it give you when you ran `git checkin`?

Comment: It looks like you ran your git config line above incorrectly, if you're receiving that response.