# Local git functions

Tags: git, bash, function, local

I figured out how to make functions for git bash to load in windows using the .bashrc file in my home folder (with the workaround of .bash_profile):

```
# Example
function cush() {
    git add Figures/;
    git commit -am "$1";   # Parse string to git
    git push;
}
```

But this function is dedicated to LaTeX and I actually only need to use it when working in specific types of repositories.
So my question is whether there is a way to make functions locally, such that it will load upon loading git bash in that specific folder?
This motivates functionality that is specific for the repository, just like .gitignore is.

Comment: Not without creating a security hole.

Comment: If you're doing a `git commit -am`, then you don't need the `git add Figures/` above it.

Comment: @hjpotter92 This covers the case where there are new, untracked files in `Figures` as well as uncommitted changes to tracked files outside `Figures/`.

Comment: @chepner ah! I confused `git add -A` with `git commit -a` :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534184) may help. I tried this solution and it could work in my Ubuntu15.x and git version 2.8.2 while the others have errors.

```
[alias] cush = !git add . && git commit -m $1 && git push && :
```

so you can add this alias into the local config and run `git cush <message>`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you don't worry about having unnecessary functions defined unless you want to use the same name for different, context-dependent functions. `bash` doesn't directly provide a hook for executing code when the working directory changes, but you can (ab)use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to conditionally execute code based on the value of `$PWD` each time a new prompt is displayed.

1. Create a directory named `.bash-functions`
2. Put your LaTex-specific functions in `.bash-functions/latex`
3. Create a file `.bash-functions/un-latex` which contains code to unset your LaTeX-specific functions, something like

   ```
   unset -f cush
   ```
4. Add the following to your `.bashrc`:

   ```
   source_local_functions () {
       source ./bash-functions/un-latex
       if [[ $PWD == foo ]]; then
           source ./bash-functions/latex
       fi
   }
   PROMPT_COMMAND=source_local_functions
   ```

Now, each time you display a new prompt, `bash` will unset your LaTex-specific functions, then reset them if you are in a directory named `foo` (you can obviously adjust this test for the real directories which should use the LaTeX functions).

This gets unwieldy if you have other directory-specific functions to define, as you need to keep track of which functions to unset and which ones to set for every change of directory.

Comment: Both answers are super useful, thank you, but I choose the other one as the solution because it works within the git system :D

Comment: That answer is far better; I completely forgot about per-repository configuration.