# Is there a git command to show new upstream commits after fetch?

Tags: git, command-line-interface, shortcut, git-log

Is there some shortcut to specify the interval of fetched, new commits from remote tracking branch? Instead of typing this long command that is also branch specific:

```
git log branchName..origin/branchName
```

I am looking for some git interval hack, that will represent interval of branchName..origin/branchName, something like (not working, equivalent to git log ..origin/HEAD)

```
git log ..origin
```

Comment: You question is: when new commit execute, show log? I think this dependency your editor. Find extension like `git log` or `git history`. You can see `git history` in Visual Studio Code:  https://github.com/DonJayamanne/gitHistoryVSCode and Atom: https://atom.io/packages/git-history

Comment: You can set up an alias to do fetch & log. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534184/git-alias-multiple-commands-and-parameters.

Comment: I was looking for some interval shortcut something like - this is completely invented by me - `git log ..origin`...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will do what you want, provided you have remote tracking configured for your branch:

```
git log ..@{u}
```

It will show all the commits on `remotes/branch` which are not already on your local `branch`.  If you want to also see your local commits which have not been pushed, use three dots:

```
git log ...@{u}
```

Or if you want to see only your local commits which have not been pushed as of your last fetch, put the two dots after `@{u}`:

```
git log @{u}..
```

Explanation:

- `@{u}` is shorthand for `HEAD@{upstream}

  - `master@{upstream}` means *the remote tracking branch for my local 'master' branch.*  `master@{upstream}` is the same as `origin/master` if your `master` branch is tracking the remote branch named `master` on the remote named `origin`.
  - If you omit the branch name (e.g. `master`) then your current branch is used instead.
  - `upstream` can be abbreviated to `u` in this case.  So `@{u}` is the same as `master@{upstream}` if your current branch is named `master`.
- `..` is used to specify a range of commits.

  - `A..B` is the same as `^A B` which means *show me all the commits in B but exclude those in A.*  It can also be written `B --not A`.
  - If you omit either reference, like `A..` or `..B`, then the omitted reference is presumed to be `HEAD`.
- You can see what your upstream tracking is configured to with `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{u}`
- You can set your upstream tracking explicitly with `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master`

You can find all the details about revision specifications like this in the [Git man pages](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html):

```
git help revisions
```

Or

```
man gitrevisions
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for, just I do not understand, why I have negative reputation for this question...

Answer (score 0):

This perhaps is not an answer but rather a long comment with a workaround you could apply to avoid re-typing the same thing over and over.

You could write yourself an alias, see example below

```
git config --global alias.branchlog \ `log branch..origin/branch`
```

`alias.<name>` - replace `<name>` with whatever you like as long as you can remember. You can call this function like this:

```
git branchlog
```

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for, see my edited question

Comment: I am sorry to hear that, I am afraid I do not know any other way how to simplify this operation. It will be interesting to see what others may post

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your time, I am also eager for information if some simpler way in git is possible.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested this.

1. Create a bash file with the command: `git log $1..origin/$1`. Name it whatever you like (I am calling it foo.sh).
2. Make sure it's executable: `chmode +x foo.sh`.
3. run the git command: `git config --global alias.branchhistory '!./path/to/foo.sh'`

Now you are ready to try it as follows: `git branchhistory master`.