# Simpler master-based workflow

Tags: git

My current master-based workflow is to develop hotfixes in `master` and new features in `develop` branch. When it's time to release I do the following:

```
git checkout master && git pull
git checkout develop && git rebase master
git checkout master && git merge develop
git push
```

Can I do the same with fewer commands? I would like to omit multiple `checkout`s if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets see.  (this assumes your remote is named `origin`)

```
git fetch origin master
git rebase origin/master develop
git checkout master && git merge --ff-only develop
git push
```

notes:

- `git rebase origin/master develop` is exactly the same as `git checkout develop && git rebase master`
- I use `--ff-only` when merging for clarity because this merge will not create any new commits, just move the branch pointer.

Ok, so the initial new code is still 4 lines, but checkout appears only once.
  You may be able to reduce the checkouts slightly by using ideas from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts), but I will ignore that.

You can further reduce your typeing (but not git execution time), by creating a **git alias** with multiple commands ([as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534184/git-alias-multiple-commands-and-parameters)) by starting the alias with an exclamation mark(`!`).

You could create an alias like so:

```
git config --global alias.pushDevelop '!git fetch origin/master; git rebase origin/master develop; git checkout master; git merge --ff-only develop; git push'
```

You would then use the command like so: `git pushDevelop`.

<sub>You could also replace the third line with `git branch -f master`, and recreate a `master` branch on `develop` branch, but that might result in a loss of tracking information. (This command forces the creation of branch `master`.  The `-f` would be required because git can not have two branches with the same name.</sub>