# How done with git fetch, checkout and pull with one command line?

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-bash

Every time I run 3 commands when I need to test my team member code on local.

Like that:

```
git fetch remote_name branch_name 
git checkout branch_name
git pull origin master
```

or

`git fetch remote_name branch_name && git checkout branch_name` etc...

Because normally after fetch it we always checkout into it than we need pull from origin master. If we can run one command to done all those step it will faster.

Does git has a command to fix that?

Comment: Create a bat file? Use a UI like [git extensions](https://gitextensions.github.io/)?

Comment: You can create an alias too.

Comment: @Liam, I use git bash on ubuntu

Comment: @KakadaNeang make an alias as @Víctor López suggests or define a simple function in `~/.bashrc`. `function foo(){ git fetch remote_name branch_name && git checkout branch_name && git pull origin master }`, then run `foo` will do the job. If `remote_name` and `branch_name` are not constant, replace them with `$1` and `$2` in the function, and run `foo remote_name branch_name`. After editing ~/.bashrc, you need to source it by `source ~/.bashrc` or restart the shell window.

Comment: It would help if you mention this in your question and/or add the relevant tags

Comment: There's another good motivation for such a combination: to get around conflicts. for example, if you switch back to an old master branch and have some locally modified files, but the current master branch would be similar to what you already have. for this reason, `git checkout` often fails and I have to do the following: `git stash && git checkout master && git pull && git stash pop` (I omit the `git fetch` because this is done by `git checkout` already)

Answer (score 3):

If you use this combination of commands often, you might want to add the function to your shell, as suggested by @ElpieKay. For example, if you use `bash` or `dash`, then adding the following code to your `~/.bashrc` will allow you to type `foo remote_name branch_name` which will be equivalent to the statements in your question.

```
function foo {
    git fetch $1 $2 && git checkout $2 && git pull origin master
}
```

If you would rather type `git foo remote_name branch_name`, it is possible to create multi-statement git aliases as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534184/git-alias-multiple-commands-and-parameters).

Comment: Why not just `git pull`? I never write `git pull origin master`. And good that you shorten the other commands as well. What the question does, taking the branch names as the parameters, is not needed.