# How to switch to master and pull latest changes with one shortcut in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to have single keyboard shortcut do to two things in IntelliJ IDEA:

- switch to master branch in Git regardless of current branch (`git checkout master`)
- pull latest changes from origin/master (`git pull --rebase --autostash origin master`)

Currently I have both configured as `External Tool` and I have separate shortcuts attached. How can I join these commands so I can prepare my local master branch for further development within one keyboard shortcut?

Or maybe there is a way to do the same without using `External Tool` feature?

Comment: What happens if you give both those commands in the same External Tool, separated by  a semi-colon

Comment: I don't use IntelliJ IDEA but, as long as you can execute a git command, you'll surely be able to define a git alias https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534184/git-alias-multiple-commands-and-parameters

Comment: @Bajal If I separate by semicolon then I get `git: 'checkout master;' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: @ludovico great idea, you can post it as an answer

Comment: I guess Romain's answer gets you covered. Alternatively, you can define your alias in a .gitconfig file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2553799/11298742). Another one is definning a shell alias ;)

Answer (score 3):

In case you didn't already come up with a good alias for that after ludovico's insightful comment, here's one named `qp` for "quick pull" but rename it as you prefer.

```
git config --global alias.qp '!f() { git checkout ${1-master}; git pull --rebase --autostash origin ${1-master}; }; f'
```

which you can use with or without a branch parameter :

```
# default usage (targets master)
git qp

# but if you ever need the same action for another branch
git qp some-feature-branch
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no UI action to do what you need, unfortunately. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171649 and related.

As a workaround, you can build a git alias (as mentioned in other replies) and use it as an external tool with a shortcut.