# Is possible to write a multi-line alias in .gitconfig?

Tags: git-config, git-alias

I know that is possible to use `&&` (and) statement to go running multiple commands for a same alias. However for long combinations it loses in readability. For example:

```
save = !git status && git add -A && git commit -m \"$1\" && git push --force && git log && :
```

**Is there a multi-line way to write it?**

Maybe wrapping it with `{}` for example?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a line escape (`\`) to break lines like this:

```ini
[alias]
   save = !git status \
        && git add -A \
        && git commit -m \"$1\" \
        && git push -f \
        && git log -1 \
        && : # Used to distinguish last command from arguments
```

You can also put multiple statements inside a function like this:

```ini
[alias]
   save = "!f() { \
           git status; \
           git add -A; \
           git commit -m "$1"; \
           git push -f; \
           git log -1;  \
        }; \ 
        f;  \
        unset f"
```

**See Also**: [Git Alias - Multiple Commands and Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7534184/1366033)

Answer (score 1):

I'd refrain from writing such extensive aliases in the config file. You can also [add new commands](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.24.0/Documentation/howto/new-command.txt) by adding an executable file named `git-newcommand` to your `PATH`. This could be a Bash script, Python script or even a binary as long as it's executable and named with the prefix "git-".

In case of scripts you've to add the proper [Hashbang](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Export the `PATH`, for example in your home:

```
export PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/bin"
```

This is more modular, portable and easier debuggable.

Comment: Another approach to avoid extensive aliases in the config file is to include an alias file, or even several, in the config, e.g. `[include] \
  path = mygitaliases.git; \
  path = morealiases.git; `