# What's the correct way to create an alias in Git?

Tags: git, cmd, alias

I'm trying to create an alias to init a repo, but it doesn't work and I'm not really sure why, this is the alias:

```
> git config --global alias.init-setinfo "git init && git config --global user.name \"myName\" && git config --global user.mail \"myMail@gmail.com\""
```

Calling it returns:

```
> expansion of alias 'init-setinfo' failed; 'git' is not a git command
```

Comment: There's little point in repeatedly setting/overwriting the *global* configuration on a per-repository basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git aliases automatically run `git` command.

That's why your alias expands to:

```
git git init && ...
```

Which explains the error you see.

One way to overcome this is to use the `!` character in the alias definition which tells Git to run it as an external command:

```
git config --global alias.init-setinfo "!git init && ...
```

Référence documentation : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

> (...) Git simply replaces the new command with whatever you alias it for. However, maybe you want to run an external command, rather than a Git subcommand. In that case, you start the command with a `!` character.

---

Edit: see also [Git Alias - Multiple Commands and Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534184/git-alias-multiple-commands-and-parameters)