# echo arbitrary arguments in git

Tags: git, git-alias

I am chaining a bunch of git commands in alias as below. How do I get the 'echo' part to work:

```
[alias]
        comb = ! sh -c 'echo \"Combining branches $1 with $2\"' && git checkout $2 && git merge $1 && git push && git checkout $1 && :
```

Some context:
[Git Alias - Multiple Commands and Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534184/git-alias-multiple-commands-and-parameters/25915221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use single quotes around `echo` — Unix shells do not expand parameters inside single quotes. The fix is

```
$ git config alias.comb '! sh -c "echo \"Combining branches $1 with $2\""'
$ git config alias.comb 
! sh -c "echo \"Combining branches $1 with $2\""
```

Example:

```
$ git comb 1 2 3                
Combining branches 1 with 2
```

Or

```
$ git config alias.comb '! sh -c "echo \"Combining branches $*\""'
$ git config alias.comb         
! sh -c "echo \"Combining branches $*\""
$ git comb 1 2 3                
Combining branches 1 2 3
```

Comment: While all the suggestions are valid solutions, this **explains** what was wrong with my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

The standard trick is to define a function which you immediately call.

```
[alias]
        comb = ! f () { echo "Combining branches $1 with $2" && git checkout "$2" && git merge "$1" && git push && git checkout "$1" && :; } f
```

This simplifies the quoting.

Comment: I agree again, this is a work around. But what is the problem with the quotes in my attempt? (Or the `echo` alias that I commented below?

Comment: The single quotes already escape the double quotes; there's no need to escape them again with a backslash. Plus, the single quotes should have surrounded the entire list of commands for `sh` to execute them, rather than having `sh` only execute `echo`. Git aliases don't take arguments, only the shell, so you need a single command that can receive arguments (either `sh` or a function`) in which to use `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: `git comb foo bar` expands to `f () { ... }; f foo bar` (or in your original case, `sh -c 'echo ...' && git ... && git ... && : foo bar`).

Comment: Thanks, along with @phd answer, I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are messed up:

```
        comb = ! sh -c 'echo "Combining branches $1 with $2" && git checkout "$2" && git merge "$1" && git push && git checkout "$1"'
```

You could also consider changing your alias to an executable called `git-comb` and store it somewhere in your path:

```
$ cat /path/to/executables/git-comb
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]
then
  >&2 printf 'Usage: %s <ref> <ref>\n" "${0##*/}"
  exit 2
fi
echo "Combining branches $1 with $2"
git checkout "$2"
git merge "$1"
git push
git checkout "$1"
```

This way you can call it with:

```
$ git comb branch_1 branch_2
```

Comment: I agree, I can create a sh script to get away. But even the following doesn't work
`comb = ! sh -c 'echo "Combining $1 with $2"'`. Or let's say, I create an alias `echo = ! sh -c 'echo "$*"'`, I expect `git echo Hello World` to work.